# How can I read a text file into a string variable and strip newlines?

Tags: python, string

I have a text file that looks like:

```
ABC
DEF
```

How can I read the file into a single-line string without newlines, in this case creating a string `'ABCDEF'`?

---

<sub>For reading the file into a *list* of lines, but removing the trailing newline character from each line, see [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines).</sub>

Comment: Related: [How to read a file line by line into a list with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3277503/3345375)

Comment: The title and the question are inconsistent. Do you really want to get rid of the \n as well?

Comment: do you really want to remove newlines from the file/string contents, or are you just confused about the many meta-characters in your print output and actually want to keep the newlines, but not have them display as "\n"?

Comment: Do you really want to read the entire text into **one string variable**?

Do you really mean with "strip newlines" to replace them with an empty string?

This would mean, that the last word of a line and the first word of the next line are joined and not separated.

I don't know your use case, but this seems to be a strange requirement.

I might have another answer if you explain what you intend to do with the read in data

Comment: @gelonida based on the answers that were given, the original question text, and which answer was accepted, that is exactly what OP wanted. The first version of the question read: "As i see data is in list form. How do i make it string. And also how do i remove \n, [, and ] characters from it ?" - suggesting severe misunderstanding of the fundamentals, but pretty adamant and clear about the desired output.

Comment: This has, for better or worse, become the closest thing we have to a canonical for the question of how to read an entire file into a single string.

Answer (score 1912, accepted):

You could use:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '')
```

Or if the file content is guaranteed to be one line:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().rstrip()
```

Comment: Is there a downside in just writing `open("data.txt").read().replace('\n','')` instead?

Comment: Yes, your version does not explicitly close the file, that will then be delayed until the garbage collector runs or the program terminates. The 'with' statement usually encapsulates some setup/teardown open/close actions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So, it seems that my version might be ok for small scripts - but OTOH it should preferably be avoided altogether to not make it a habit.

Comment: @tuomassalo it is a huge PITA in the test/debug process, as it won't clean up the open file handles if you have to terminate prematurely or it runs into an exception.

Comment: that `replace('\n','')` could be simply `rstrip('\n')`

Comment: No, `rstrip('\n')` will only remove the newline from the last line, `replace('\n','')` removes it everywhere (essentially making the whole file one line)

Comment: You don't need to state the `"r"` explicitely, as it is the default value for the `mode` option (but it might be good just for clarification).

Comment: -1 because the `replace('\n')` will change the formatting of the input data.  xiaoyu's answer is more accurate.  (The `\n` and `[]` appear only because of the use of `readline()`.)

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou: You are mistaken, the `\n` (newline character) is contained in the input. `readlines()` splits at occurrences of it, but leaves them intact.

Comment: @sleeplessnerd : Indeed my comment parenthesis is poorly worded, but that's precisely my point : the OP doesn't *really* want to get rid of them.  See also Alex Dupuy's comment to xiaoyu's answer.

Comment: this question/answer ranks very high on search engines for people looking to read a file into a string. unfortunately this snippet does something else/destructs newlines. probably not out of spite, but simply because the original author of the question is bit confused about the meta-characters in his output... BUT THIS IS PROBABLY NOT what most people looking for `def as_string(filepath)` are looking for!

Comment: Can I access data when file is closed? If I don't indent `data` under `with`?

Comment: Is it really the case that we have to wait for the GC to close the file if we do not explicitly close it? I thought Python also has reference counting (and GC just for cyclic refs). After the line data = open(...).read() there will be no reference to the file object anymore and it can be closed.

Comment: @Nils

It depends entirely on the implementation of python when a file is closed, that does not use the `with` statement.

Up to my knowledge C-python would destroy the file handle as soon as the file object 's reference counter goes down to 0, but other implementations liek jythojn or pypy might do differently.

Also if you have a long living function, then the with statement ensures, that the file is closed as soon as possible

Answer (score 287):

In Python 3.5 or later, using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text) you can copy text file contents into a variable *and close the file* in one line:

```
from pathlib import Path
txt = Path('data.txt').read_text()
```

and then you can use [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to remove the newlines:

```
txt = txt.replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: This is so far the most elegant solution. I prefer to have a oneliner solution like R's read_file

Comment: When I use pathlib, I get this error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 148: character maps to <undefined>`.
And as far as I search, it seems I can't set encoding to pathlib, so I have to read the content traditionally with the os module.

Comment: @AliAkhtari Per the docs, the signature is `read_text(encoding=None, errors=None)`. You should be able to pass the encoding there?

Answer (score 113):

You can read from a file in one line:

```
str = open('very_Important.txt', 'r').read()
```

Please note that this does not close the file explicitly.

[CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) will close the file when it exits as part of the garbage collection.

But other Python implementations won’t. To write portable code, it is better to use `with` or close the file explicitly. Short is not always better. See *[Is explicitly closing files important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/is-explicitly-closing-files-important/7396043#7396043)*

Comment: This is anti-idiomatic and not recommended. `open` should be used within a `with ... as` statement.

Comment: @J.C can you explain the problem ? Is this just a question of custom or does the `with ... as` statement bring something ?

Comment: @Titou the issue is that open.read() doesn't close the file so we either need `with ... as` or `str.close()` as demonstrated in Pedro's answer. More on the importance of closing files [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/is-explicitly-closing-files-important)

Comment: @JBallin. This idiom clearly removes a source of error. Thanks !

Comment: this is also bad because you've just shadowed `str()` from builtins

Comment: Downvoted. The code should also show how to close the string, even if CPython often does it for you. Leaving this code line to the comments is not enough. It is also unclear *when* CPhython is running: "Written in C and Python, CPython is the default and most widely used implementation of the Python language.", see Wiki. Thus, it does not always run, and you also say that keeping it portable is better, so why not also show the code to close the string?

Answer (score 67):

To join all lines into a string and remove new lines, I normally use:

```
with open('t.txt') as f:
  s = " ".join([l.rstrip("\n") for l in f])
```

Comment: It is giving UnicodeDecodeError in my code See this https://stackoverflow.com/q/18649512/9339242

Comment: you may need to specify the character encoding.

Comment: will remove trailing white space as well

so perhaps better to `s = " ".join([l.replace("\n", "") for l in f]) `

Comment: @gelonida `rstrip` also supports specifying the charter(s) you want to remove, thanks for the tip.

Comment: thanks as well. I forgot that `rstrip()` also has an argument.
So your code is probably faster and operational except for some really weird cases where **one** line would contain a mix of trailing `" "` and `"\n"` like `"funny line \n \n  "`

Answer (score 35):

Use:

```
with open("data.txt") as myfile:
    data = "".join(line.rstrip() for line in myfile)
```

[join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) will join a list of strings, and [rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) without any arguments will trim whitespace, including newlines, from the end of strings.

Answer (score 20):

There is also [splitlines()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
with open ("data.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read().splitlines()
```

Variable `data` is now a list that looks like this when printed:

```
['LLKKKKKKKKMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNN', 'GGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEEEEEEE']
```

Note there aren't any newlines (`\n`).

At that point, it sounds like you want to print back the lines to console, which you can achieve with a for loop:

```
for line in data:
    print(line)
```

Comment: That's because OP *didn't want* the output to be a list of strings, but a single string - at least as far as anyone could confirm. This answer would be suitable on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines, but I'm pretty sure it's already well covered there.

Answer (score 19):

This can be done using the [read()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) method:

```
text_as_string = open('Your_Text_File.txt', 'r').read()
```

Or as the default mode itself is 'r' (read) so simply use,

```
text_as_string = open('Your_Text_File.txt').read()
```

Comment: Note that this keeps the file open indefinitely.

Answer (score 12):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're after, but something like this should get you started:

```
with open ("data.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data = ' '.join([line.replace('\n', '') for line in myfile.readlines()])
```

Comment: reduce(lambda x,y : x+y.rstrip('\n'), ['a\n', "b\n", 'c'], "") is a lot cooler :D

Comment: @Duncan what would you suggest?

Comment: `data = ' '.join(line.replace('\n', '') for line in myfile)` or MagerValp's version.

Answer (score 12):

I have fiddled around with this for a while and have prefer to use use `read` in combination with `rstrip`. Without `rstrip("\n")`, Python adds a newline to the end of the string, which in most cases is not very useful.

```py
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    file_content = f.read().rstrip("\n")
    print(file_content)
```

Answer (score 12):

Here are four codes for you to choose one:

```py
with open("my_text_file.txt", "r") as file:
    data = file.read().replace("\n", "")
```

or

```py
with open("my_text_file.txt", "r") as file:
    data = "".join(file.read().split("\n"))
```

or

```py
with open("my_text_file.txt", "r") as file:
    data = "".join(file.read().splitlines())
```

or

```py
with open("my_text_file.txt", "r") as file:
    data = "".join([line for line in file])
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also strip each line and concatenate into a final string.

```
myfile = open("data.txt","r")
data = ""
lines = myfile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    data = data + line.strip();
```

This would also work out just fine.

Comment: `data = data + line.strip();` can be reduced to `data += line.strip();`

Comment: very inefficient for huge files (a lot of memory allocations and memory copies will take place. better to create list of stripped lines and then use " ".join()`

Answer (score 6):

You can compress this into one into two lines of code!

```
content = open('filepath', 'r').read().replace('\n', ' ')
print(content)
```

If your file reads:

```
hello how are you?
who are you?
blank blank
```

Python output

```
hello how are you? who are you? blank blank
```

Comment: I like this solution as the last word of a line will be separated by a space from the first word of the next line.

However I would suggest to use the `with` statement. So something like 
`with open("filepath", "r") as fin: content = fin.read().replace("\n", " ")`

But if course it's nit sure whether this is needed by the original poster

Answer (score 5):

```
f = open('data.txt','r')
string = ""
while 1:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:break
    string += line

f.close()


print(string)
```

Comment: Loops which have a `string += line` should be avoided. Some versions of Python may manage to avoid O(n^2) behaviour here but any of the other answers that have been given are better than this. Also you didn't remove the newlines that were requested so your code is just a very slow way of doing `string = f.read()`

Comment: Thank for correcting me. But one small thing is that I have not to remove the new line, because when I tested, it didn't print '\n' out. @Duncan

Comment: very inefficient for huge files. for every iteration memory has to be allocated and data has to be copied.

Also: the new line is neither removed nor replaced with a " "

Try to use following command to see, that the new lines are still contained.

`print(repr(string))`

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8369232/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 5):

[Python 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_3): See *[List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)* for the square bracket syntax.

```
 with open('data.txt') as f:
     lines = [ line.rstrip('\n') for line in f ]
```

Comment: Very pythonic and worked for me quite well, although I haven't tested on large files yet.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to be retracting my upvote because strip also strips whitespace, which may not be the desired behavior.  However, I still think a modified version of this would be good.

Comment: `lines = list(map(str.strip, f))`?

Comment: strip() and rstrip() do not remove whitespace if an argument is passed (unless whitespace is in the argument).

Comment: Long overdue thanks on clarification on strip() and rstrip()!
Reference document: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip 
(via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990694/strip-vs-lstrip-vs-rstrip-in-python )

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
x = "yourfilename.txt"
y = open(x, 'r').read()

print(y)
```

Comment: This is wrong. You want   y = open(x, 'r').read()  if you're going to do it that way.

Answer (score 4):

This is a one line, copy-pasteable solution that also closes the file object:

```
_ = open('data.txt', 'r'); data = _.read(); _.close()
```

Comment: Please don't do this, use a `with ... as` as one should.

Answer (score 4):

#### Oneliner:

- List: `"".join([line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('file.txt')])`
- Generator: `"".join((line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('file.txt')))`

List is faster than generator but heavier on memory. Generators are slower than lists and is lighter for memory like iterating over lines. In case of "".join(), I think both should work well. .join() function should be removed to get list or generator respectively.

- Note: close() / closing of file descriptor probably not needed

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
from pathlib import Path
line_lst = Path("to/the/file.txt").read_text().splitlines()
```

It is the best way to get all the lines of a file. The '\n' are already stripped by the `splitlines()` (which smartly recognize win/mac/unix lines types).

But if nonetheless you want to strip each lines:

```
line_lst = [line.strip() for line in txt = Path("to/the/file.txt").read_text().splitlines()]
```

`strip()` was just a useful exemple, but you can process your line as you please.

At the end, do you just want concatenated text?

```
txt = ''.join(Path("to/the/file.txt").read_text().splitlines())
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove line breaks using Python you can use `replace` function of a string.

This example removes all 3 types of line breaks:

```
my_string = open('lala.json').read()
print(my_string)

my_string = my_string.replace("\r","").replace("\n","")
print(my_string)
```

Example file is:

```
{
  "lala": "lulu",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

You can try it using this replay scenario:

https://repl.it/repls/AnnualJointHardware

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't feel that anyone addressed the [ ] part of your question. When you read each line into your variable, because there were multiple lines before you replaced the \n with '' you ended up creating a list. If you have a variable of x and print it out just by

x

or print(x)

or str(x)

You will see the entire list with the brackets. If you call each element of the (array of sorts)

x[0]
then it omits the brackets. If you use the str() function you will see just the data and not the '' either.
str(x[0])

Answer (score 2):

You could try this. I use this in my programs.

```py
Data = open('data.txt', 'r')
data = Data.readlines()
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = data[i].strip() + ' '
data = ''.join(data).strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression works too:

```
import re
with open("depression.txt") as f:
     l = re.split(' ', re.sub('\n',' ', f.read()))[:-1]

print (l)
```

Output:

> ['I', 'feel', 'empty', 'and', 'dead', 'inside']

Answer (score 1):

This works:
Change your file to:

```
LLKKKKKKKKMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNN GGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEEEEEEE
```

Then:

```
file = open("file.txt")
line = file.read()
words = line.split()
```

This creates a list named `words` that equals:

```
['LLKKKKKKKKMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNN', 'GGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEEEEEEE']
```

That got rid of the "\n". To answer the part about the brackets getting in your way, just do this:

```
for word in words: # Assuming words is the list above
    print word # Prints each word in file on a different line
```

Or:

```
print words[0] + ",", words[1] # Note that the "+" symbol indicates no spaces
#The comma not in parentheses indicates a space
```

This returns:

```
LLKKKKKKKKMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNN, GGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEEEEEEE
```

Comment: Changing the file might work in a one off situation but if you have hundreds of files this just isnt a workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = [line.strip('\n') for line in file.readlines()]
    data = ''.join(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
with open(player_name, 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.readline()
    list = data.split(" ")
    word = list[0]
```

This code will help you to read the first line and then using the list and split option, you can convert the first line word separated by space to be stored in a list.

then you can easily access any word, or even store it in a string.

You can also do the same thing with using a *for* loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("myfile.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
str = ''                                     #string declaration

for i in range(len(lines)):
    str += lines[i].rstrip('\n') + ' '

print str
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37785427/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -3):

Try the following:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

    sentences = data.split('\\n')
    for sentence in sentences:
        print(sentence)
```

Caution: It does not remove the `\n`. It is just for viewing the text as if there weren’t any `\n`.