# Handling .txt files in AppEngine Blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

Refering to the example in the link:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview

In the example above, a `Model` named `_BlobInfo_` is created to store the blob.

Is there a way to store and retrieve blobs using user defined models:
eg:

```
class DummyText(db.Model):
  ptxt = db.BlobProperty()
```

Note: I need to handle ".txt" file in the above model. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `.txt` files you could actually use the [`TextProperty()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties) which can fit up to 1MB using `db` and unlimited size for `ndb`. In the background they are actually stored as blobs but it's much easier since blobs are immutable and cannot be changed.

I would suggest you also to upgrade to [`ndb`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/).

Comment: I tried to use the TextProperty(), but how can you convert the uploaded file to the text format. I use "upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')", but how can i retrive the .txt file contents once uploaded

Comment: There is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-in-python) for that.

Comment: Can you give me a simple code snippet to do so,considering im uploading a text file using " <input type="file" name="ftxt" />", What exactly should my python class in appengine do to retrive its contents. Thanks

Comment: I also found the below thread to be useful. [Stack Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186583/retrieving-txt-file-contents-in-google-appengine) and see [Blog.NotDot](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Handling-file-uploads-in-App-Engine) for storing any file-types in blobstore. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#BlobReferenceProperty) in your model to store references to blobstore keys.