# super simple python program - substituting whitespaces with newlines?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program with python. 
I want to substitute whitespaces in a txt document with new lines. 
I have tried writing it myself but my output file gets filled with weird characters. 
Can you help?
:)

Comment: you should post what you tried

Comment: Disregard all answers with a for loop in it. A `f.read()` reads the whole file. Looping over lines is too expensive if you don't need that explicitely.

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer that helped you the most as solution by clicking the green tick under the voting box of that answer.

Comment: actually it's not working well, only worked on some sentences and not on others. this was my code: import re

with open('diviso.txt') as f, open('diviso2.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in f:
        new_line = re.sub('\s', '\n', line)
        # print new_line
        out.write(new_line)

Comment: why did it not work on all sentences :(?

Comment: I also tried this code: with open("text.txt", 'r') as oFile:
    lResults = [line.replace(" ", "\n") for line in oFile]

with open("results.txt", "w") as oFile:
    oFile.writelines(lResults)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
lResults = list()
with open("text.txt", 'r') as oFile:
    for line in oFile:
        sNewLine = line.replace(" ", "\n")
        lResults.append(sNewLine)

with open("results.txt", "w") as oFile:
    for line in lResults:
        oFile.write(line)
```

Here an "optimized" version after the suggestions in the comments:

```
with open("text.txt", 'r') as oFile:
    lResults = [line.replace(" ", "\n") for line in oFile]

with open("results.txt", "w") as oFile:
    oFile.writelines(lResults)
```

EDIT: Response to comment:

> hey sebastian - I just tried your code, it keeps giving me the weird
>   characters in the output file! am i doing something wrong with it? –
>   Freddy 1 min ago

What do you mean by "weird" characters? Do you have a non-ASCII file?
Sorry, but for me it works perfectly fine, I just tested it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: hey sebastian - I just tried your code, it keeps giving me the weird characters in the output file! am i doing something wrong with it?

Comment: hey, I responded in the answer above

Comment: If you are on a *nix system (or using cygwin on Windows), I would write to stdout rather than a new file. This gives you the power to just print it out, redirect it `>` to a file of your choice, or pipe it `|` to another program.

Comment: I am on windows, using txt document. I have tried again, this time the output file is empty :(

Comment: hm, sorry, I don't know much about windows. I think I can't help you there.

Comment: Kudos for providing such a roundabout answer. But sadly the code is not optimal. However, with your approach you will be one of the best Python coders fast! Keep up the good work!

Comment: Good answer, but I'd prefer a list comprehension here. `lResults = [line.replace(" ", "\n") for line in oFile]`, secondly when writing the content of that list(`lResults`) to that output file, simply use: `oFile.writelines(lResults)`. No need of a loop at all. And one more thing better use `str.translate`, it is 5 times faster than `str.replace`.

Comment: ah cool, sounds reasonable. Will apply it next time I have to write sth. similar like this!

Comment: I just tried the optimized code on my sentences - it works on some but not on all :(

Comment: can you post an example, that would be helpful to account for those special cases

Comment: I went to a shop that sold organic food and bought everything.
I do not think the upswing will start before spring next year.
The registration of students and all grants and loans have been suspended.
Mr
Howell
is
convinced
that
the
tea
market

Comment: this is an example, some of these were divided (from Mr Howell onwards), the others weren't :(

Comment: my file has around 600 of these sentences

Comment: ok, i think i know why it didn't work - i pasted the text from an excel document. now, extracting the text from the tables and THEN pasting it into the txt document worked like a wonder! sorry for that!

Comment: Hehe, I am really confused now, but if it worked, great ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import re
s = 'the text to be processed'
re.sub(r'\s+', '\n', s)
=> 'the\ntext\nto\nbe\nprocessed'
```

Now, the "text to be processed" above will come from the input text file, that you previously read in a string - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-in-python) for details on how to do this.

Comment: (And if you want *every* whitespace character swapped for a `\n`, get rid of the `+`. (@Oscar's solution will convert multiple spaces in a row to only one `\n`))

Comment: thanks! Will this work on a file of 600+ sentences?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with regular expressions:

```
import re

with open('thefile.txt') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in f:
        new_line = re.sub('\s', '\n', line)
        # print new_line
        out.write(new_line)
```

You probably need to write back `new_line` to a file instead of printing it :) (==> snippet edited).

---

See the python [`regex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) documentation:

```
sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

- `pattern`: the search pattern
- `repl`: the replace pattern
- `string`: the string to be processed, in this case, `line`

**Note**: if you only want to substitute whitespaces which occur at the end of the line, use the `\s$` search pattern, where `$` stands for the end of the string (so that reads "a space at the end of the string"). If you really need to replace just every space, then the `replace` method of `str` is probably enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
def (in_file, out_file):
  with open(in_file, 'r') as i, open(out_file, 'w') as o:
     w.write(i.read().replace(' ', os.linesep))
```

Notice that this neither loops nor writes `'\n'` but instead `os.linesep` which will be `\n` on Linuxes and `\r\n` on Windows and so on.

Also notice that the biggest part of the answer comes from [alwaysprep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17890909/131120) and he should get the credit for it, if he takes the loop out of his solution. (Did he actually deleted his answer? Can't find it anymore.)

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with using a loop, using `file.read()` puts the whole file content into memory, which is not memory efficient at all.

Comment: Only seldomly will you hit memory limitations with text files. And without the loop you gain faster iteration (in the underlying interpreter, not in your code) and better maintenance because of less code. "Simple is better then complex."