# how to visualise results in Spyder?

Tags: python, output, spyder

I was trying to read a txt file in python. After the following input:

```
f = open("test.txt","r") #opens file with name of "test.txt"
print(f.read(1))
print(f.read())
```

instead of looking at the text I'm returned this:

[image]

how do i visualize the output?

Thanks

Comment: there isn't a repr function in that object.  what are you trying to put the end product in?

Comment: just wanted to read the txt in the console

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go line by line.  Be careful, if its a big text file this could go on for awhile.

```
for line in f:
    print line.decode('utf-8').strip()
```

some strings not being read correctly, so you'll need the decode line.

See:[UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649512/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2-in-position-13-ordinal)

Comment: it doesn't work. I get the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: can you share what your text file looks like?

also take a look at my edited answer - see that error message's solutions

Answer (score 0):

try this setup...
it worked for my console printing problems:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```