# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on scraping [Oregon Teacher License data](http://www.tspc.oregon.gov/lookup_application/lookup_query.asp) for a project I'm doing. Here's my code:

```
educ_employ = tree.xpath('//tr[15]//td[@bgcolor="#A9EDFC"]//text()')
print educ_employ
#[u'Jefferson Middle School\xa0\xa0(2013 - 2014)']
```

I want to strip the the "\xa0". This is my code:

```
educ_employ = ([s.strip('\xa0') for s in educ_employ])
print educ_employ
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649512/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2-in-position-13-ordinal):

```
educ_employ = ([s.decode('utf-8').strip('\xa0') for s in educ_employ])
print educ_employ
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte):

```
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

educ_employ = tree.xpath('//tr[15]//td[@bgcolor="#A9EDFC"]//text()')
educ_employ = ([s.decode('utf-8').strip('\xa0') for s in educ_employ])
print educ_employ
>>>
```

I didn't get an error with the last one but I also didn't get an output. I'm using Python 2.7. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: see the "common idiom" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374455/how-to-set-sys-stdout-encoding-in-python-3

Comment: @mpez0 that is for Python 3, the question is about Python 2

Comment: @mpez0 Sorry I'm having trouble understanding what's going on. What is `codecs` represent?/I'm fairly new to programming so this is a little over my head.

Comment: @otteheng just ignore them :D however if you are not absolutely required to use Python 2, I recommend switching to Python 3, it makes dealing with text / unicode easier.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks for the advice!

Comment: The problem here (considering Python 2), doesn’t seem to `s`, but to `'\xa0'` itself. Try `.strip(u'\xa0')` instead.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala did you look at the "common idiom" for python2 portion of my linked reply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up `unicode` objects and `str` objects. `educ_employ` is a `unicode`, but `'\xa0'` is a `str`.

Additionally, `.strip()` only removes characters from the beginning and end of the string, not the middle. Try `.replace()` instead.

Try:

```
educ_employ = [u'Jefferson Middle School\xa0\xa0(2013 - 2014)']
educ_employ = [s.replace(u'\xa0', u'') for s in educ_employ]
print educ_employ
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great. I actually tried `.replace` before but it didn't work. I noticed that you include a `u` in your code. Just curious what that means and why it makes a difference?

Comment: String literals without the `u` are objects of type `str` String literals with the `u` are  objects of type `unicode`. The essence of my answer is "don't mix `str` and `unicode`;"  adding `u` to the string literal demonstrates that.

Comment: That makes a lot sense. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @otteheng again, this confusion does not exist on `python3`