# how to replace non ascii char in python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I need to replace non ASCII char like `¾` in Python but I get

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file test.py but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details`
```

After following the directions [on the webpage](http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html), I am getting

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 449: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's my code:

```
data = data.replace(u"½", u"1/2")
data = re.sub(u"¾", u"3/4", data, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

What do I need to change in my code?

---

my file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with codecs.open("file.txt", "r", "utf8") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

data = data.replace(u"½", u"1/2")
```

file.txt is:

```
hello world ½
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space

Comment: @TusharGupta this remove the char ...

Comment: If it can remove it, you can use it to replace it. Try something  ;)

Comment: I did try a lot, that is why I am asking, I am out of ideas now

Comment: can you provide the the content (or a small part of it ) of  `data`?

Comment: @BillBEGUERADJ the data varies between 100 b to 1k, mostly english with "¼½¾" char inside

Comment: The error should be raised by the `open` call, not by the `replace` call. Show the complete stacktrace and the relevant code.

Comment: The encoding you specify needs to match the encoding that your editor uses when you save the file. What editor are you using? Are you on Windows?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy ubuntu 15, pycharm gui,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading into the local variable `data` as bytes but then treating `data` it like it's already a unicode object.

Change this:

```
with open(file_name, "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
```

To this:

```
import io

with io.open(file_name, encoding="utf8") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
```

Comment: Still get: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to read it as unicode but pyhton reads it as a string. Try this, the question looks similar to your `UnicodeDecodeError`

> > https://stackoverflow.com/a/18649608/5504999

Try adding `#coding: utf-8` on top of your file. This will allow the usage of Non-ASCII characters.

Comment: I get: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\uf057' in position 383: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Did you try reading your first parameter in replace() with **u.decode('utf-8')**?

Comment: Look at @wim's answer.

Comment: I tried: with codecs.open(HTML_PATH + file_name, "r", "utf8") as myfile: data = myfile.read() data = data.replace(u"½", u"1/2") and i get: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file

Comment: Try my answer, i.e., add `#coding: utf-8` on top of your file. It allows program to read non-ascii characters.

Answer (score -1):

I think your initial string is not properly encoded as unicode.

What you are attempting works just fine:

```
>>> st=u"¼½¾"
>>> print st.replace(u"½", u"1/2")
¼1/2¾
```

But the target needs to be unicode to start with.

Comment: that's exactly what my code do: `data.replace(u"½", u"1/2")` but does not work

Comment: `data` is not a unicode string. That is why it is not working for you. Look at wim's answer.

Comment: I tried:     with codecs.open(HTML_PATH + file_name, "r", "utf8") as myfile:
data = myfile.read()
data = data.replace(u"½", u"1/2") and i get: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file