# UnicodeDecodeError when instaling new package

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install a package that I have used many times with python 2.7 and ubuntu 14.04, however it fails now with following error:

```
Cleaning up…
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py”, line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File “/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py”, line 278, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
File “/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py”, line 1198, in prepare_files
do_download,
File “/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py”, line 1376, in unpack_url
self.session,
File “/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py”, line 582, in unpack_http_url
unpack_file(temp_location, location, content_type, link)
File “/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py”, line 643, in unpack_file
untar_file(filename, location)
File “/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py”, line 574, in untar_file
path = os.path.join(location, fn)
File “/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py”, line 80, in join
path += ‘/’ + b
UnicodeDecodeError: ‘ascii’ codec can’t decode byte 0xe2 in position 47: ordinal not in range(128)

Storing debug log for failure in /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log
```

I googled around and it supposed to be a locale error, I managed to set locale to en_us.utf-8 it didn’t change anything. I don’t understand much about these settings, so I don’t know what to do next.

Could anybody help me out with this?

The package name is AllAuth and it fails with any version, new old, everything fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this executing

export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8

try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649512/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2-in-position-13-ordinal). Might be helpful for you.

Comment: Tried, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the package you're trying to install is Python 2 compatible. More and more modules are migrated to Python 3 and the new version handles unicode characters differently than version 2.

Comment: It is compatible, I ask for a specific version that is older but compatible with my Python and code.

Comment: Are there any unicode characters in your filepath where you run pip or where you have your virtualenv installed. The character that throws an error is: â. Maybe look for it in the downloaded lib?