# Python 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 151: ordinal not in range(128) AWS Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, character-encoding, aws-glue

I have a Python script that is running in AWS Glue. Up until last month is was working fine and I ran into the following error.

I've seen *several* different nasty hacks suggested on SO and am having issues trying to figure out how to implement correct answers in my script: [UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649512/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2-in-position-13-ordinal)

`'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 151: ordinal not in range(128)`. It looks like this character is an `em dash` - more than likely was user entered and this script did not take that into account when I wrote it. I've looked up other issues with this on SO but a lot of them involve nasty hacks that I'd rather not implement. My Python is very sparse (glue generates most of the boilerplate). How can I modify my script to negate this encoding error?

```
import boto3
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

# @params: [JOB_NAME, database, path, company_id, user_id]
args = getResolvedOptions(
    sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'database', 'path', 'company_id', 'user_id'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database=args['database'], table_name="employee_data", transformation_ctx="datasource0")
filtered_data = Filter.apply(
    frame=datasource, f=lambda x: x["company_id"] == args['company_id'])
filtered_data = Filter.apply(
    frame=filtered_data, f=lambda x: x["email"] == args['user_id'])


def get_diffs(rec):
    diff_length = 0
    try:
        diff_length = len(rec["diffs"])
    except:
        pass

    if diff_length > 0:
        for key, value in rec["diffs"].items():
            if len(value) > 0:
                rec[key] = {}
                rec[key]["old"] = value[0]
                rec[key]["new"] = value[1]
                rec[key]["timestamp"] = rec["timestamp"]
                rec[key]["action"] = rec["action"]
                rec[key]["source"] = rec["source"]
                rec[key]["requester"] = rec["requester"] if rec["requester"] != None else ""
                rec[key]["employee"] = rec["email"]
                rec[key]["field"] = key
        del rec["diffs"]
    else:
        rec["0"] = {}
        rec["0"]["old"] = ""
        rec["0"]["new"] = ""
        rec["0"]["timestamp"] = rec["timestamp"]
        rec["0"]["action"] = rec["action"]
        rec["0"]["source"] = rec["source"]
        rec["0"]["requester"] = rec["requester"] if rec["requester"] != None else ""
        rec["0"]["employee"] = rec["email"]
        rec["0"]["field"] = ""

    del rec["payload"]
    del rec["partition"]
    del rec["timestamp"]
    del rec["source"]
    del rec["action"]
    del rec["requester"]
    del rec["email"]
    del rec["company_id"]
    return rec


filtered_data = Map.apply(
    frame=filtered_data, f=get_diffs)

new_data_rdd = filtered_data.toDF().rdd

new_data = new_data_rdd.flatMap(
    lambda row: (
        (
            row
        )
    )
)

new_data = new_data.filter(lambda x: x)
schema = StructType([StructField('action', StringType(), False), StructField('field', StringType(), False), StructField('old', StringType(), False), StructField('employee', StringType(
), False), StructField('source', StringType(), False), StructField('timestamp', StringType(), False), StructField('requester', StringType(), False), StructField('new', StringType(), False)])
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_rdd(
    new_data, name='unpivoted', schema=schema)

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame=datasource0, mappings=[("timestamp", "string", "date", "string"), ("employee", "string", "employee", "string"), ("action", "string", "action", "string"), ("field", "string", "employee_field_changed", "string"), (
    "old", "string", "previous_value", "string"), ("new", "string", "new_value", "string"), ("source", "string", "source", "string"), ("requester", "string", "changed_by", "string")], transformation_ctx="applymapping1")


repartition = applymapping1.repartition(1)
file_path = "s3://"+args["path"]+"/audit_log/" + \
    args["company_id"]+"/"+args["user_id"]
datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=repartition, connection_type="s3", connection_options={
                                                         "path": file_path}, format="csv", transformation_ctx="datasink2")

client = boto3.client('s3')
prefix = "audit_log/"+args["company_id"]+"/"+args["user_id"]
audit_key = prefix+"/audit.csv"
client.delete_object(Bucket=args["path"], Key=audit_key)
response = client.list_objects(Bucket=args["path"], Prefix=prefix)
name = response["Contents"][0]["Key"]
client.copy_object(Bucket=args["path"],
                   CopySource=args["path"] + "/" + name, Key=audit_key)
client.delete_object(Bucket=args["path"], Key=name)

job.commit()
```

Here is the traceback

```
Log Contents:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runscript.py", line 63, in <module>
    default_error_msg = "
{}
: 
{}
".format(e_type.__name__, str(e_value).split("\n")[0])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 151: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need any nasty hacks running modern Python in the cloud (I hope).  Can you share the complete error traceback so that we can see where the error is occurring?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I've added the trackback. Keep in mind that AWS Glue runs this. `runscript.py` is AWS-specific.

Comment: ew that's not nice.  It looks as if `runscript` is trying to raise an exception, but the content of the exception message contains non-ASCII characters.  Are you able to reproduce this outside of the AWS environment?  Alternatively, are you able to change the AWS environment so that is uses a locale that supports UTF-8? (I'm not very familiar with AWS I'm afraid)