# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8'/'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 31

Tags: python, pandas, csv, error-handling, python-unicode

I have an input csv file and when I try to do some operations on it and make an output file, I am getting this error.

At first I got the 'utf-8' Error so I searched and checked the encoding of my file with this:

```
import chardet
with open('1out_test.csv', 'rb') as rawdata:
    result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(100000))
result
```

Output: {'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}

Then I wrote the following:

```
WORDS, N = ["aaaa", "tttt"], 1

pattern = (
    rf"((?:\S+ +){{0,{N}}}\S*"
    fr"\b(?:{'|'.join(map(re.escape, WORDS))})\b"
    rf"\S*(?: +\S+){{0,{N}}})"
)

pd.read_csv("1out_test.csv", encoding='ascii', low_memory=False).assign(info=lambda x: x["remarks"].str.extract(pattern,flags= re.IGNORECASE, expand=False).fillna("NA")).to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

This again gave me the same error but with 'ascii':
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)

NOTE: In both the errors, the position 31 was the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649512/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2-in-position-13-ordinal)

Comment: 0xe2 is `â` in ISO-8859-1, so if your CSV-File contains that character, ISO-8859-1 is the encoduing you are looking for.

Comment: @treuss Or ISO-8859-15.

Comment: I have tried a similar approach; encoding is 'ascii' for my input file but still shows the error. The top answer in the given post is doing which I don't think is applicable to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
pd.read_csv("1out_test.csv", encoding='ascii', low_memory=False).assign(info=lambda x: x["remarks"].str.extract(pattern,flags= re.IGNORECASE, expand=False).fillna("NA")).to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

with:

```
pd.read_csv("1out_test.csv", encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False).assign(info=lambda x: x["remarks"].str.extract(pattern,flags= re.IGNORECASE, expand=False).fillna("NA")).to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Hey @Suley! I have already tried that, it gives me the error:
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 31: invalid continuation byte