# Content of text file as a input to python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want that the content of a text file to be used as a input for my python script. This is my script. I want to replace few words:

```
import subprocess
import fileinput
import sys
import os

for line in text:
    line = line.replace("/dev/sda3              ", "")
    line = line.replace("/dev/sda6              ", "")
    line = line.replace("/dev/sda2              ", "")
    line = line.replace("/dev/sda1              ", "")
    line = line.replace("tmpfs                  ", "")
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: ...so what's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open ("data.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
```

Take a look at [How do I read a text file into a string variable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-in-python)

Comment: This will replace words for each instance?

Comment: I am not sure what you want, but it imports a text file into a string while replacing a part of it (in this case the line break (\n). It is replaced in the string not in the file as you can see from the 'r'-Option (read) in the open command. If you want to do that several times, than do it several times.