# Open text file either locally or remotely via url with python

Tags: python

I am working on a project where I will need to potentially open and read a textfile either on a local server or remotely (via url). Is there a python function that works like php's :

```
file_get_contents()
```

that can do this?  right now I have:

```
def get_data_from_file(path):

    for i, line in enumerate(open(path)):
        .....
```

I would like to pass in a path either locally or remotely.

Comment: What do you mean by a textfile "on a local server" or "remotely"? If it's just an SMB, NFS, AFP, etc. share, you just open it; nothing above the level of the filesystem cares where the share comes from. If it's, say, an FTP or HTTP URL, or a file that you can access by `ssh`ing into a system and then reading it, or something different… well, then the answer depends on which of those it is.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to roll your own . . . `try` to open the file.  If you fail, then `try` to use `urllib2` to open the url.  Then return the file object for the caller to use how they wish  (or raise a suitable exception neither succeeds). . .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read a text file into a string variable in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-in-python)

Comment: sorry, the remote textfile is available via a url eg http://stackoverflow.com/mytextfile.txt . I'm just wondering if there is a unified command that can do both in python like file_get_contents() in php

Comment: If it's _always_ a URL (including a file: URL for whatever "local server" means), you can just always use `urllib` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
def file_get_contents(path):
  try:
    urllib.urlretrieve(path, filename=path)
  except:
    print 'not a page'

  if os.path.exists(path):
     with open(path, r) as file:
        data = file.read()
        print data
  else:
    print 'no such file'
```