# Extracting data using regular expressions: Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7, data-extraction

The basic outline of this problem is to read the file, look for integers using the `re.findall()`, looking for a regular expression of `[0-9]+` and then converting the extracted strings to integers and summing up the integers.

I am finding trouble in appending the list. From my below code, it is just appending the first(0) index of the line. Please help me. Thank you.

```
import re
hand = open ('a.txt')
lst = list()
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    stuff = re.findall('[0-9]+', line) 
    if len(stuff)!= 1  : continue
    num = int (stuff[0])
    lst.append(num)
print sum(lst)
```

Comment: Can you show what some of the lines in `'a.txt'` look like?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Below link will redirect to whole the text in the file. http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_325354.txt

Answer (score 0):

Great, thank you for including the whole txt file! Your main problem was in the `if len(stuff)...` line which was skipping if `stuff` had zero things in it and when it had 2,3 and so on. You were only keeping `stuff` lists of length 1. I put comments in the code but please ask any questions if something is unclear.

```
import re
hand = open ('a.txt')
str_num_lst = list()
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    stuff = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    #If we didn't find anything on this line then continue
    if len(stuff) == 0: continue
    #if len(stuff)!= 1: continue #<-- This line was wrong as it skip lists with more than 1 element

    #If we did find something, stuff will be a list of string:
    #(i.e. stuff = ['9607', '4292', '4498'] or stuff = ['4563'])
    #For now lets just add this list onto our str_num_list
    #without worrying about converting to int.
    #We use '+=' instead of 'append' since both stuff and str_num_lst are lists
    str_num_lst += stuff

#Print out the str_num_list to check if everything's ok
print str_num_lst

#Get an overall sum by looping over the string numbers in the str_num_lst
#Can convert to int inside the loop
overall_sum = 0
for str_num in str_num_lst:
    overall_sum += int(str_num)

#Print sum
print 'Overall sum is:'
print overall_sum
```

EDIT:

You are right, reading in the entire file as one line is a good solution, and it's not difficult to do. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-in-python). Here is what the code could look like.

```
import re

hand = open('a.txt')
all_lines = hand.read() #Reads in all lines as one long string
all_str_nums_as_one_line = re.findall('[0-9]+',all_lines)
hand.close() #<-- can close the file now since we've read it in

#Go through all the matches to get a total
tot = 0
for str_num in all_str_nums_as_one_line:
    tot += int(str_num)

print('Overall sum is:',tot) #editing to add ()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew I was doing wrong at if len(stuff)... line. I was not able figure it out the aproach. '+=' is the right option. Thanks for sharing that. And as an entry level programmer, I am wondering if  can we read() the whole file as a single string and use '[0-9]+' from the string to extract?

Comment: Yes, good point! I've edited my answer to include that option

Comment: That;s great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
ls=[];
text=open('C:/Users/pvkpu/Desktop/py4e/file1.txt');
for line in text:
    line=line.rstrip();
    l=re.findall('[0-9]+',line);
    if len(l)==0:
        continue
    ls+=l
for i in range(len(ls)):
    ls[i]=int(ls[i]);
print(sum(ls));
```