# Load a txt file in Python

Tags: python, file, text, pygame

I have a simple question here. I have two numbers in a txt file and I am trying to create a method that can change two variables in my code for those two numbers in the txt file.

Here is my method:

```
def loadCoords(cordX, cordY):
    i=0;
    f1 = open( 'continue.txt', "r")
    f2 = open( 'continue.txt', "r")
    f1.readline();
    while i<2:
        f2.readline();
        i=i+1;
    #already tested>>> cord=f.readline()   xD
    #also tried to put another names for the cordX and cordY here inside  xD
    cordY=f2;
    cordX=f1;
    return cordX;
    return cordY;
```

Here is where I am calling the method:

```
if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evento.key == pygame.K_a:
                   print('GAME BEGIN')
                   GAME_BEGIN = True
                   loadCoords(cordX,cordY);
```

Someone could help?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: no one, it just can't read the f1 and f2 files,  coordX and Y printing 0 and 0 , the numbers that i've been declared at the beggining.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a text file into a string variable in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forget, it is done, hahaha                                                                                `def loadCoords():
    f1 = open( "continue.txt", "r")
    text=f1.read()
    num_list=text.split()
    print (num_list)
    cordX=num_list[0]
    print(cordX)
    cordY=num_list[1]
    f1.close()

    return cordX,cordY`

Answer (score 0):

The method `f1.readline()` returns something, but you aren't using the returned result (which would be as list in this case). Put the functions output into a variable (like this `f1_content = f1.readline()`).

Comment: `readline()` does exist though. Also, there's no need writing "Sorry for bad English" when you're pretty much writing fluently.

Comment: On, thank you, I always think I made a mistake... anyway. I was just irritated by readline(), but yes, it exists

Comment: haha hello, i already tested your guess before @YpsilonZett,but tks for the helping, when i solve i public the answer,

Comment: Ok, fine, but I've learned something new, the readline() function ;)!

Answer (score 0):

If your text file contains two numbers in separate line then use this

```
def loadCoords():
    f1 = open( 'continue.txt', "r")
    text=f1.read()
    num_list=text.split(sep='\n')

    cordY=int(num_list[0])
    cordX=int(num_list[1])
    f1.close()
    return cordX,cordY
```

Don't use two returns in your Function , because the first return will exit from the function , and you lose whatever you return next.

If you are loading two co-ordinates from a text file then why you are passing two arguments to you function, instead load the return value.

```
cordX,cordY=loadCoords()
```

Comment: tks for your help and hint @Rakesh_K , i just tried to change my script to your and i have the error :  _cordX=int(num_list[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '52 150'_

Comment: i've never had a problem like this before, maybe could be those '' that the console are reading(but i don't have this in my file)... what do you think it is?? tks

Comment: forget, it is done, hahaha                                                                                'def loadCoords():
    f1 = open( "continue.txt", "r")
    text=f1.read()
    num_list=text.split()
    print (num_list)
    cordX=num_list[0]
    print(cordX)
    cordY=num_list[1]
    f1.close()  
    return cordX,cordY'

Comment: @Aury0n if the problem is resolved you can accept the answer