# Reading information from .txt in python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, input

I  have  .txt file that has 6 lines on it.

```
Line 1 name 
Line 2 eamil address 
line 4 phone number 
line 5 sensor name 
line 6 link .
```

I want to read those 6 lines in python and forward an email to the email address listed in the second line. I have a script that does this . But I don't know how to do this from .txt file . 
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Comment: Actually, in retrospect, "Too Broad" is probably a better close reason, as this question asks how to do multiple things.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("filename", "r") as f:
    for l in f:
      // do your processing, maybe keep track of how many lines you see since you need to do something different on each line
```

Answer (score 0):

You said email lies in the second line of the file?

you can manipulate txt files by line using the readline() function.

usage example:

text file:

```
John Smith
john@smith.tld
line3
1-800-smth-here
sensorname
link

file = open(“testfile.txt”, “r”) 
client_email = file.readline(1)
print client_email
```

would result in

```
john@smith.tld
```

Comment: Thanks , but it only reads the first two letters from the first line not the second line when I put :client_email = file.readline(2)

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at this question: [How do I read a text file into a string variable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8369219/2519977)

It shows you how to read a file line per line into an array.

So you can do:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
     data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
```

`data[1]` would then be the email address.

Please do proper research before asking.

Comment: It's inappropriate to post an answer that tells a user to look at another question. Please flag such questions as duplicates.

Comment: I thought it was a borderline-duplicate as he added a little new aspect of assigning it to a variable, but you are right.