# NameError in a Function (python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I need to define a function that opens a text file, reads it, then loads the entire file into a string. This is what I have so far:

```
def encrypt_file(filename):
    open_file = open(filename, 'r')
    file_content = filename.read()
    filename.close()

encrypt_file(filename)
user_input = input('enter file name: ')
```

This is the error I get:

> encrypt_file(filename)
>   NameError: name 'filename' is not defined

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So, what _is_ `filename` in `encrypt_file(filename)`? Did you mean to pass `user_input` instead?

Comment: `filename.read()` is also wrong.  You'll need to do `open_file.read()` and `open_file.close()` instead.

Comment: What kind of function is `encrypt_file()`? it does practically nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The `filename` var is not defined yet, you have to swap lines a little bit:

```
filename = input('enter file name: ')
encrypt_file(filename)
```

Also some intro to   [How To Handle Plain Text Files in Python 3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-plain-text-files-in-python-3)
 and SO question: [How do I read a text file into a string variable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-in-python) would be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work anyway.

```
def encrypt_file(filename):
    open_file = open(filename, 'r')
    file_content = open_file.read()
    open_file.close()

some_filename = input('enter file name: ')
encrypt_file(some_filename)
```

Best Practice:

```
def encrypt_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as open_file:
        file_content = open_file.read()
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps what you want to do is:

```
def encrypt_file(filename):
    open_file = open(filename, 'r')
    file_content = filename.read()
    open_file.close()

filename = input('enter file name: ')
encrypt_file(filename)
```

Please note also the correction on the line `open_file.close()`.