# Saving text file in a for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop through a file, strip the sentences into individual lines, and then export that data.

```
filename = '00000BF8_ar.txt'

with open(filename, mode="r") as outfile:   
    str_output = outfile.readlines()
    str_output = ''.join(str_output)
    sentenceSplit = filter(None, str_output.split("."))

    for s in sentenceSplit:
        print(s.strip() + ".")
        #output += s 



        myfile = open(filename, 'w')
        myfile.writelines(s)
        myfile.close()
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the loop only goes through a few lines and saves them. So the whole file isn't looped through and saved. Any help on how I can fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a text file into a string variable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-in-python)

Comment: Your loop truncates the file every time it opens it. Why are you reopening the file *at all*, rather than opening it once before the loop?

Comment: if you use readlines() it read all the line in the file and save them in a list, if you want read line to line use readline() or you read everything and then you make the loop on the list

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I hope this is what you want to achieve,

```
filename = '00000BF8_ar.txt'

with open(filename, mode="r") as outfile:   
    str_output = outfile.readlines()
    str_output = ''.join(str_output)
    sentenceSplit = filter(None, str_output.split("."))
    l=[]

    for s in sentenceSplit:
        l.append(s.strip() + ".")
    myfile = open(filename, 'w')
    myfile.write('\n'.join(l))
    myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you re-open the file with the `'w'` option, you basically erase its content.

Try modifying your code like this:

```
filename = '00000BF8_ar.txt'

with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    str_output = infile.readlines()

str_output = ''.join(str_output)
sentenceSplit = filter(None, str_output.split("."))

with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    for s in sentenceSplit:
        print(s.strip() + ".")
        #output += s 
        s.writelines(s)
```

Another way to achieve the same thing would have been to open a new file using `open(filename_new, 'a')` which open a file for appending, but as a rule of thumb try not to open/close files inside a loop.

Answer (score 1):

`open(filename, 'w')` will overwrite the file every time it starts. My guess is that what's currently happening is that only the last element in `sentenceSplit` is showing up in `myfile`.

The simple "solution" is to use `append` instead of `write`:

```
open(filename, 'a')
```

which will simply start writing at the end of the file, without deleting the rest of it.

However, as @chepner's comment states, why *are* you reopening the file at all? I would recommend changing your code to this:

```
with open(filename, mode="r") as outfile:   
    str_output = outfile.readlines()
    str_output = ''.join(str_output)
    sentenceSplit = filter(None, str_output.split("."))

with open(filename, mode='w') as myfile:
    for s in sentenceSplit:
        print(s.strip() + ".")
        myfile.writelines(s)
```

This way, instead of opening it many times, and overwriting it every time, you're only opening it once and just writing to it continuously.