# How would I load text files within a module in python?

Tags: python, module

I have a python project that contains multiple modules and one module contains a .txt file of a long list of keywords.

How would I access the .txt file and load its content (the list of strings) into a variable in a .py script from another location (not the same directory)??

```
--- Library
         - Module_Alice
              - etc..
         - Module_Bob
              - assets
                   - audio
                   - video
                   - texts
                        - all_keywords.txt
              - unittests
                   - func 
                        - test_text_process.py
```

I need to load all keywords in `all_keywords.txt` into a variable in  `test_text_process.py`

Comment: Using relative paths

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a text file into a string variable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-in-python)

Comment: @mad_ what would the relative path be like? I've tried different things but only the absolute path worked.

Comment: ok '../../assets/text/all_keywords.txt'  worked. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
with open("../../assets/texts/all_keywords.txt") as f:
    keywords = f.readlines()
```

Now that `keywords` list variable contains all keywords on the file.

Comment: the relative path doesn't work:  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../assets/text/all_keywords.txt'

Answer (score 3):

Use `open`

You can use absolute path:

```
with open("/root/path/to/your/file.txt",'r') as fin:
    # Your reading logic
```

Or you can use relative path:

```
with open("../../your/file.txt",'r') as fin:
    # read it.
```

In the case you'll move the folder around and run it in other place, but not on the level of the python file, you might want to do relative import in this way:

```
import os.path as path
text_file_path = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)) + '/assets/texts/all_keywords.txt'
```

This way you can run your python file anywhere and still be able to use the text file. If you just do a relative you can't run your python from outside of its directory, i.e. like `python path/to/script.py`

Comment: what would the relative path be like? I've tried different things but only the absolute path worked.

Comment: say you're running `test_text_process.py`, the relative path would be `'../assets/texts/all_keywords.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

This will read the file into a list of strings from that location.

```
with open('../assets/text/all_keywords.txt') as infile:
    list_of_strings = infile.readlines()
```

Comment: the relative path doesn't work:  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../assets/text/all_keywords.txt'

Comment: Depends on where you are running the file from. It may be `'Module_Bob/assets/text/all_keywords.txt'` or `'Library/Module_Bob/assets/text/all_keywords.txt'`