# From Text file to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, arraylist

I have a file which contains list of lists, its a text file, and it looks like that:

```
    [[ שומר
 ,קולורבי
 ,קיווי
 ,"תפו""ע פינק ליידי"
 ,גזר
 ,עגבניה
 ,Unknown
 ] ,
[ מארז נייצ'ר ואלי שיבולת שועל עם שבבי שוקולד
 ,פיטנס חטיפי פריכיות דקות קינמון 60 גרם
 ,פריכיות משולשות פלפל
 ,מארז נייצ'ר ואלי שיבולת שועל עם שבבי שוקולד
 ,Unknown
 ,בננה
 ,"תפו""ע פינק ליידי"
 ,"תפו""ע גרנד"
 ,מארז 5 חטיפי פרי דגנים תמר תפוח ללא סוכר
 ,Unknown
 ] ,
[ "תפו""א לבן ארוז דוד משה"
 ,כרוב לבן
 ,קישוא
 ,גזר
 ,בטטה
 ] ,
[ Unknown..........
```

I need to convert it to pandas DataFrame, like wide columnstore, just one list = one row.
Any help would be amazing! I am working with Jupyter Notebook - Python 3.

Comment: What's your desired output look likes?

Comment: @Yoav Barzilai to make list of lists into rows : `df = pd.DataFrame(list)`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I need it to be a dataframe that every row is a list, every value is a nubmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file text and try below code -

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = open('data.txt', 'r', encoding = 'windows-1255', errors='ignore').read().replace("\r","").replace("\n","")


remove_doulequotes = data.replace('""', '').replace('"', '')
list_of_str = list(map(lambda x: '"{x}"'.format(x=x), remove_doulequotes.split(",")))
final_data = ", ".join(list_of_str).replace('"[[', '[["').replace(']"','"]').replace(']]"', '"]]').replace('"[', '["').replace(']"]', '"]]')

data_in_list = json.loads(final_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_in_list)
```

Or You can use `ast.literal_eval` function also -

```
import ast

data = open('data.txt', 'r', encoding = 'windows-1255', errors='ignore').read().replace("\r","").replace("\n","")

remove_doulequotes = data.replace('""', '').replace('"', '')
list_of_str = list(map(lambda x: '"{x}"'.format(x=x), remove_doulequotes.split(",")))
final_data = ", ".join(list_of_str).replace('"[[', '[["').replace(']"','"]').replace(']]"', '"]]').replace('"[', '["').replace(']"]', '"]]')

data_in_list = ast.literal_eval(final_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_in_list)
```

Additional codes added for string manipulation to format string properly.

Comment: Hey and thanks for the reply, my data is in a text file.

Comment: I mentioned that read file then store that in data named variable then you can able to reuse the code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-and-strip-newlines

Comment: @YoavBarzilai edited answer. You can read a file in multiple ways.

Comment: @YoavBarzilai using ast is the best approach. Check more details on same here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

Comment: @YoavBarzilai Improved answer, very rough code added to format strings.

Comment: Hey and thanks for your help but im not getting what im trying to achive, I can send you a print screen if you like. this is my mail yoav.barzilay98@gmail.com

Comment: @YoavBarzilai Sure.

Comment: @YoavBarzilai Improved answer, as per your file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
with open('txt.txt') as f:
    lst = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Should give you what you want.