# Issue writing .txt with python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble writing .txt with python.
So i first read one .txt file, then split it, and rearrange then write it out to another .txt file.

Here's my code

```
# Read objects 
objectit = open('objects.txt', 'r') 
Lines = objectit.readlines() 


# SpawnObjects writing
count = 0
objectit = open('SpawnObject.txt', 'w')
for line in Lines:
    test = line.split('|', 3)
    objline = ("SpawnObject( ", "\"",test[0],"\"", ", " , "\"",test[1],"\"", ", " , "\"",test[2],"\"" , ");\n")
    print("SpawnObject( ", "\"",test[0],"\"", ", " , "\"",test[1],"\"", ", " , "\"",test[2],"\"" , ");\n")
    objectit.writelines(objline)
objectit.close()
```

Input data looks like this:

```
bldr_Game_wall_5m|13751.722656 46.671505 2962.292480|-155.094345 0.000000 -2.000000
Barrier_4m|13783.922852 41.197544 2915.867920|134.620407 0.000000 2.000000
randomObject|13793.672852 40.633644 2912.021484|136.797043 0.000000 3.000002
```

And this is what i get when i run this through script.

```
SpawnObject( "bldr_Game_wall_5m", "13751.722656 46.671505 2962.292480", "-155.094345 0.000000 -2.000000
");
SpawnObject( "Barrier_4m", "13783.922852 41.197544 2915.867920", "134.620407 0.000000 2.000000
");
SpawnObject( "randomObject", "13793.672852 40.633644 2912.021484", "136.797043 0.000000 3.000002
");
```

I don't know why `");"` is going to another row. But i've tried multiple things to fix this. Whole point was to automate this step, and currently i still have to do manual labor

To be clear, **below** is the example of data i'd like to get.

```
SpawnObject( "randomObject", "13793.672852 40.633644 2912.021484", "136.797043 0.000000 3.000002");
SpawnObject( "Barrier_4m", "13783.922852 41.197544 2915.867920", "134.620407 0.000000 2.000000");
SpawnObject( "randomObject", "13793.672852 40.633644 2912.021484", "136.797043 0.000000 3.000002");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a text file into a string variable and strip newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-and-strip-newlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "objects.txt" file has new lines in it and you are copying them over when you print "test[2]".

You can't see them, but your file looks like this:

```
bldr_Game_wall_5m|13751.722656 46.671505 2962.292480|-155.094345 0.000000 -2.000000\n
Barrier_4m|13783.922852 41.197544 2915.867920|134.620407 0.000000 2.000000\n
randomObject|13793.672852 40.633644 2912.021484|136.797043 0.000000 3.000002\n
```

You need to remove the newlines. A solution to this is to "strip trailing white space" with `rstrip()`.

```
# Read objects 
objectit = open('objects.txt', 'r') 
Lines = objectit.readlines() 


# SpawnObjects writing
count = 0
objectit = open('SpawnObject.txt', 'w')
for line in Lines:
    test = line.rstrip().split('|', 3) # <---- CHANGE HERE
    objline = ("SpawnObject( ", "\"",test[0],"\"", ", " , "\"",test[1],"\"", ", " , "\"",test[2],"\"" , ");\n")
    print("SpawnObject( ", "\"",test[0],"\"", ", " , "\"",test[1],"\"", ", " , "\"",test[2],"\"" , ");\n")
    objectit.writelines(objline)
objectit.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually didn't know that, but you learn from your mistakes. Nonetheless, works flawlessly now!

Answer (score 1):

`line` ends with a newline, so `test[2]` has a newline at the end of it.

Use `rstrip()` to remove the newline:

```
for line in Lines:
    test = line.rstrip().split('|')
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! That worked!  It works perfectly now.