# Remove paragraphs and spaces (and tabs) from a txt file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, format

Suppose I have a file named "file.txt".

1. First I would like to open the file.txt file and delete all paragraphs from the file,
2. Then I would like to delete all spaces in the file (which also include tabs),
3. Finally, I would like to save the file file.txt with the previous changes.

Example of desired input:

```
Text1 Text2 Text3
Text4 Text5 Text5
```

Example of expected output:

```
Text1Text2Text3Text4Text5Text6
```

How could I do this with Python?

Comment: can you show us what you have done so far ? 

a combination of [remove white space from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string) and [open a file as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-and-strip-newlines) will probably work for you

Comment: Thanks you all, best regards