# Trying to return the length of the longest line in a string - Python

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to return the length of the longest line in a given string. Currently, my output is just reading "1".
Help?
This is what I have so far.

```
def longest_line_length(file_name):
    print(max(len(line) for line in file_name))
def main():
    print(longest_line_length('poem.txt'))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is poem.txt a file that you want to open or is it the actual string?

Comment: The file I want to open.

Comment: Try removing len()

Comment: Then you will first need to open it before you can find the longest string.

Comment: try this ```print(line) for line in file_name```
It will be ["p", "o", "e", "m", ".", "t", "x", "t"] and this should help point out your issue

Comment: Well I want it to return the length of the longest line in poem.txt (which happens to be 35). "poem.txt" isn't the actual string itself

Comment: @questionerofdy actually, it will print: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1

Comment: @Mick sorry I edited the comment a bunch 

Look at this answer to see how to read a txt file and read into a string
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-and-strip-newlines

Comment: You're not actually opening the file; you're just operating on the file _name_.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
We expect you to check the operation of your program, and to work through applicable tutorials before you post a question.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with you did not read the file. First we have to open the desired file to be red and go through the lines (reading). Then we can find the length of the particular lines. Here I have written a simple snippet. Please check whether this works for you.

```
def txtFile_reader(txtFile_location):
    length_list = []
    with open(txtFile_location, 'r') as txt_file:
        for i, line in enumerate(txt_file.readlines(), 1):
            length_list.append((len(line.strip()), i))
    return max(length_list)[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This returns which line contains the longest string, if you need to see the string count as wellm then `return max(length_list)` . It will return a tupple containing first element denoting the string count followed by the line number. `(xxx, xx)`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add two lines to your code.

```
def longest_line_length(file_name):
    data_file = open(file_name, "r")
    lst = [line.rstrip("\n")for line in data_file]
    return (max(len(line) for line in lst))
def main():
    print(longest_line_length('poem.txt'))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This prints out "34 // None" while the answer should just be "35". I added "+1" to the print line, so it then prints 35, but the "None" still remains. How would I rid of this?

Comment: @heth123 You want the length of the line or the line?

Comment: The length of the line

Comment: @heth123 check my answer

Comment: @heth123 Easy.  Change the print statement to return.  I just modified my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the line

```
def longest_line_length(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file:
        return max([line for line in file])
```

If you want the length

```
def longest_line_length(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file:
        return max([len(line) for line in file])
```

Comment: I think there must be a syntax here (in the one for the length), as it's telling me there's an error at `def main():` in my program, when there hadn't been before and nothing changed.

Comment: @heth123 Weird, it works fine for me. What error does it throw?

Comment: File "/home/main.py", line 17
    def main():
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @heth123 Oh lol, I was missing a parenthesis at the end