# Storing contents of each individual text file to a list

Tags: python, list, text, nltk

I'm trying to store the *entire* contents of each text file to an element in a list.

I've tried doing this using nltk but it puts every letter of the text as an element in the list which is not what I want.

Is there any way of doing this using nltk or normal python as the only examples I have seen online put each line as an element whereas I want the entire document.

My code:

```
textfile_list = [file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt ........ file76.txt]

for f in textfile_list:
    
    file_text=nltk.data.load('/user/documents'+f)
    text+= file_text


print(text)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a text file into a string variable and strip newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-and-strip-newlines)

Comment: No @hopperelec it still does it letter by letter

Answer (score 2):

**Try this one**, it should store each text file to an element in the list.

```
textfile_list = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
list=[]
for f in textfile_list: 
    file_text=open(f,'r').read()
    list.append(file_text) 


print(list[0])
print(list[1])
print(list[2])
```