# Writelines() doesn't write

Tags: python, python-2.7

Running this code creates file2.txt as expected, but the file is empty.  (Note:  file1.txt just has the lines of a poem.)  Why does this happen? How can I get it to write array a2 to a text file?

```
import copy

#Open input file, read it into an array, and remove the every other line.
f = open('file1.txt','r')
a1 = f.readlines()
a2 = copy.deepcopy(a1)
f.close
for n in range(len(a1)):
    if n%2 == 0:
        a2.remove(a1[n])

# Open output file and write array into it.
fo = open('file2.txt','w')
fo.writelines(a2)
fo.close
```

Comment: `fo.close()` - you are missing parentheses.

Comment: Your snippet works fine even without invoking the close method.

Comment: Note  that you're using no arrays in your code, but lists instead (which is the "proper" way to do it, but it's still worth knowing).

Comment: Everyone seems to be overlooking the fact that python [automatically closes file descriptors and flushes buffers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/python-is-explicitly-closing-files-important) when `fo` goes out of scope (in this case, when the program terminates), so not actually calling close here is meaningless (for the program behaviour, at least)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'close' is a method -- ie.  use fo.close() in place of fo.close

Answer (score 2):

you need a `()` after `close`:

```
fo.close()
```

Also consider using the [`with`](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example) statement when working with files.

Answer (score 2):

You do realise this is better written as:

```
from itertools import islice
with open('input') as fin, open('output','w') as fout:
    every_other = islice(fin, None, None, 2)
    fout.writelines(every_other)
```

Reasoning:

- File isn't loaded into memory for no reason
- `islice` can be used to create a generator for every other line
- ... which can then be passed to the output's `.writelines()`
- the `with` statement (context manager) automatically closes the files afterwards
- It's (IMHO) easier to read and understand what the intention is

Comment: or simply: `with open('text1.txt','r') as f, open('file2.txt','w') as g: g.writelines (x for i, x in enumerate (f) if i % 2)`. I don't understand the magic of itertools if a simple generator does the same trick.

Comment: @Hyperboreus because `enumerate` and modulus are un-necessary overhead handled by `islice` in this case

Comment: @Hyperboreus also - for change purposes - it's easier to adapt to take every 7th line skipping the first 50, and only up until the 2000th etc...

Answer (score 1):

As the comment said, your forgetting to close the file, so the buffer is never flushed.

replace

```
fo.close
```

with

```
fo.close()
```