# Do I have to explicitly close a file which was opened only for reading in Jython?

Tags: python, file-io, jython

I have the following piece of code:

```
for line in open(fileName, 'r'):
    <do something>
```

Initially, I would assume that there is no need to close a file opened as read only, however after I have read through the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7396043/1119381) question, it seems that I **do** have to close it, since Jython don't use reference counting and therefore won't close the file at the end of the loop.

How do I do that in this case, when I didn't define a file handler which I can close? Is such approach(as above) to open and read files is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is safest and most portable to clean up after yourself. Just save the filehandle and close it after you are done with it.

Too bad there's no `with` in Jython at the moment. That would be the perfect solution here.

```
# wouldn't it be nice if we could just...
with open(fileName, 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        # do something ...
```