# How to add all count rows in multiple csv file

Tags: python, csv, count

I have multiple CSV files and want to count all row for each file without the title column. The result will display all file records count and total records count :

[image]

The following code will count all CSV file record with title columns

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
files = glob.glob('Folder/*.csv')
d = {f: sum(1 for line in open(f)) for f in files}
print (pd.Series(d))
print (pd.Series(d).rename('rows').rename_axis('filename').reset_index())
```

Questions: How to get the following results:
Expect result

File1    3   Without Title column Row count

File2    3   Without Title column Row count

File3    2   Without Title column Row count

Total    8

Reference link: [How to count rows in multiple csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320868/how-to-count-rows-in-multiple-csv-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas solution:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = "C:/Users/username"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith(".csv")]

output = pd.Series(name="Rows", dtype=int)
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file))
    output.at[file.replace(".csv", "")] = df.shape[0]
output.at["Total"] = output.sum()

>>> output
File1    3
File2    3
File3    2
Total    8
Name: Rows, dtype: int64
```

CSV solution:

```
import os
import csv

path = "C:/Users/username"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith(".csv")]

output = dict()
for file in files:
    with open(os.path.join(path, file)) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        output[file.replace(".csv", "")] = sum(1 for row in reader)-1
output["Total"] = sum(output.values())

>>> output
{'File1': 3, 'File2': 3, 'File3': 2, 'Total': 8}
```

Comment: Hi not_speshal. Do you add total for all file rows count? I get error message when run your code: "<ipython-input-2-2f8da0059072>:7: DeprecationWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  output = pd.Series(name="Rows")"

Comment: @Anson - Edited my answer to include the "Total" and silence the warning.

Comment: Hi Not_speshal,  Your solution is good. Could you add print (output) in your code? I will accept your solution

Comment: Hi not_speshal, Can I export the result to excel file? Thanks

Comment: For the pandas Series, you can use: `output.to_csv("output.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('Folder/*.csv')
d = {}
total = 0
for f in files:
    with open(f, 'r') as out:
        nb_row = len(out.readlines())
        d[f.replace(".csv", "")]= nb_row
        total += nb_row
print(d)
print("Total", total)
```

Comment: Hi Clément Perroud. I get this error"UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 3823: character maps to <undefined>. We may need to change encoding?
"