# How do you close a file within a python list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, h5py

I'm trying to pluck values out of many HDF5 files and store in a list.

```
import h5py
h = [h5py.File('filenum_%s.h5' % (n),'r')['key'][10][10] for n in range(100)]
```

This list comprehension contains the values at grid point (10, 10) in the 'key' array from the HDF5 files `filenum0.h5`-`filenum99.h5`.

It works, except that it stops around the 50th element with the error:
`IOError: unable to open file (File accessibilty: Unable to open file)`
even though I know the file exists and it can be opened if I haven't opened many other files. I think I get the error because too many files have been opened.

Is there a way to close the files within this list comprehension?
Or, is there a more effective way to build the list I want?

Comment: You can't, you'd be better off with a traditional loop.

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45929510/4531270

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By doing like you're doing, you don't control when the file is closed.

You can control that, but not with a one-liner. You need an auxiliary method which returns the data, and closes the file (using a context manager is even better as `h5py` files support that, I just checked)

```
def get_data(n):
    with h5py.File('filenum_%s.h5' % (n),'r') as f:
        return f['key'][10][10]
```

then

```
h = [get_data(n) for n in range(100)]
```

You could make the `get_data` function more generic by not hardcoding the 10 & 'key' arguments of course.

Comment: actually this should not be done, mutable operations should not be perform in comprehensions. Maybe you forgot to return the result in the function?

Comment: Does `h5py.File()` not support the context manager interface?

Comment: It does, yes... Sorry, not returning the result, my bad!!

Comment: You don't really need the intermediate `result` variable as you can simply `return f['key'][10][10]` and the `with` will handle that appropriately.

Comment: that's true (remains of the old-style method) edited.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of argument, you *could* do everything in one single terrible list comprehension like this:

```
import h5py
h = [(f['key'][10][10], f.close())[0]
     for f in (h5py.File('filenum_%s.h5' % (n),'r') for n in range(100))]
```

But I would strongly advise against something like that, and prefer instead an auxiliary function or some other approach.

Comment: yes, as building an object for the side effect isn't recommended. But that's cool enough. pylang linked answer is also a good lead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45929510/4531270