# Python way to compare the values from file A and B and if A matches then print Entire line from B

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two text files:

myfile1:

```
sports1
sports2
sports3
sports4
sports5
sports6
sports7
sports8
```

myfile2:

```
sports1  Cricket
sports2  golf
sports3  Hocky
sports4
sports5  Chess
sports6  Snooker
sports7  Foosball
sports8  Tampts
```

From the two files above, f column one in `myfile1` matches with column one in `myfile2` then it should print both columns of `myfile2`.

The awk one-liner below works, but I am looking for a similar one in Python.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1]' myfile1 myfile2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, if you wish, use a 3rd party library such as Pandas. This is likely as close as you'll get to your one-liner.

`delim_whitespace=True` ensure Pandas uses whitespace to separate your columns, as opposed to `,` which you would expect from a regular csv.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', header=None, names=['sport'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', header=None, names=['sport', 'name'],
                  delim_whitespace=True)

res = df2[df2['sport'].isin(df1['sport'].unique())]

print(res)
```

Comment: This is great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an option, you could do the same with lists and dictionaries. Considering [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840880/will-using-list-comprehension-to-read-a-file-automagically-call-close), you can open files inside comprehensions, which will be closed after the execution. Although the best approach to such task is to use "with" as context manager.

```
f1 = [x.strip("\n") for x in open("myfile1.txt")].sort()
f2 = {x[0]: x[1] for x in [l.split() for l in open("myfile2.txt")]}
if f1 == list(f2.keys()).sort():
    [print(k, v) for k, v in f2.items()]
```

Comment: thx for the alternative soluton, However, it gives Index error..

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./user_group_identifier4.py", line 4, in <module>
    f2 = {x[0]: x[1] for x in [l.split() for l in open("file2.txt")]}
  File "./user_group_identifier4.py", line 4, in <dictcomp>
    f2 = {x[0]: x[1] for x in [l.split() for l in open("file2.txt")]}
IndexError: list index out of range
`