# Is there way to close a file in python, without a file object?

Tags: python

I can't close this file, as the file is directly fed into the 'lines'-list.

I have tried closing with command lines.close() but it doesn't work.

```
def readfile():
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('8ballresponses.txt', 'r')]  
    print(random.choice(lines))
```

I don't get an error, but i want to be able to close the file.

Comment: ``with open() as somename:`` automatically closes the file

Comment: You should use `with open('8ballresponses.txt', 'r') as your_file:` and it will be auto-closed at the end of the `with` block.

Comment: `open('8ballresponses.txt', 'r').close()` Maybe?

Comment: @Sid That would render the `open()` pretty much useless.

Comment: @Sid I doubt it. In this case, you would open the file and close it immediately. How would you then read from it?

Comment: Close it afterwards, I meant. It was a guess. Sorry guys!

Comment: CPython will automatically close the file once it's out of scope (so in this case, after the list comprehension is done), but this is not guaranteed for all Python implementations.

Comment: @L3viathan this is not even _garanteed_ by the CPython implementation - it's currently the case, has been for decades and will possibly still be the case for some times, but it's an implementation detail no one should rely upon (for production code at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `file` object, `lines` is a `list` , so you can't close it. And you should store file object `open('8ballresponses.txt', 'r')` with a variable for closing it later:

```py
def readfile(file_path):
    test_file = open(file_path, 'r')
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in test_file]
    test_file.close()
    print(random.choice(lines))
```

Or simply use `with` "to close a file in python, without a file object":

```py
def readfile(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as test_file:
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in test_file]
        print(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `with` open command. this will automatically handle all the test cases failure etc. (inbuild try except and finally  in python)

below is example similiar to  your code

```
import random

def readfile():
    lines = []
    with open(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\read.txt",'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    print(random.choice(lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `with` this will close implicitly after the block is complete

```
with  open('8ballresponses.txt', 'r') as file:
      lines = [ line.rstrip("\n") for line in file ]
```

Comment: files are iterable, so the call to `file.read()` is useless and eats memory for no reason.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I tried and you are right changed it

Comment: Also you may want to use `line.rstrip("\n")` instead of replace (it's faster since it only looks at the end of the string).

Answer (score 0):

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840880/will-using-list-comprehension-to-read-a-file-automagically-call-close)
"When the `with` ends, the file will be closed. This is true even if an exception is raised inside of it."

You manually invoke the close() method of a file object explicitly or implicitly by leaving a with open(...): block. This works of course always and on any Python implementation.

Comment: Such "answers" are not really helpful. Please do not just post a link, but the essence of its content and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try` and `finally` block to do the work.

For example :

```py
def readfile():
    file = open('8ballresponses.txt', 'r')
    try:
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]  
        print(random.choice(lines))
    finally:
        file.close()
```

Comment: dont u think this will give error if file not exist