# Print out first word in each row from .txt file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, file-handling

I'm working on a program that takes student names and grades from a .txt file and produces results. The text file has this type of form:

```
Darnell 96 54 94 98 76

Brody 50 65 65 65 70 

Anna 76 54 76 76 76

Conor 95 95 95 95
```

I want the first line of the output to show the names of students, like so:

```
Name of students in class:
Anna Brody Conor Darnell
```

My current code is

```
   f = open(argv[1])
   while True:
      line = f.readline().strip()
      if line:
         print(line)
```

I know I need to used the `sorted()` function. However, when I try to do implement it I just make a mess of the code.

I know theres similar questions out there. However, being new to python some are way over my head.
Any little bit of information helps. Thanks!

Comment: "I want the first line of the output to show the names of students, like so:" --> first line or first word?? Why are you using while True??

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

I suggest using `with open(...)` because you don't need to explicitly use `close()`.

```
with open(argv[-1]) as f:
    names=[]
    for line in f:
        names.append(line.split()[0])

print(*sorted(names),sep=' ')
#Anna Brody Conor Darnell
```

As suggest by @Jan you can write all of that using a list comprehension.

[Does using list comprehension to read a file automagically call close()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18840920/12416453)
 I wrote the below in accordance with this link.

```
print(*sorted([line.split()[0] for line in open('score.txt','r') if line.split()]),sep=' ') #This single code does what you wanted
#Anna Brody Conor Darnell
```

---

But I suggest using this answer below.

```
with open(argv[-1],'r') as f:
    print(*sorted([line.split()[0] for line in f],sep=' ')
```

---

Use this if you have a line gap between lines.

```
with open('score.txt','r') as f:
        names=[]
        for line in f:
                if line.strip():
                        names.append(line.split()[0])
print(*sorted(names),sep=' ')
```

Comment: You may want to use a listcomp.