# Converting list of strings to floats from data file

Tags: python

my code produces this result

```
[['1.2', ' 4.3', ' 7', '0'], ['3', ' 5', ' 8.2', '9'], ['4', ' 3', ' 8', '5.6'], ['8', ' 4', ' 3', '7.4']]
```

but i want to remove the ' '

```
def main():
    my_list = [line.strip().split(',') for line in open("Alpha.txt")]
    print(my_list)


main()
```

i attempted to convert the list into floats but it keeps returning errors. I need a way to convert the current list in this format into floats.

```
[float(i) for i in lst]
```

this hasnt worked for me because it seems to error out when trying to use float(my_list)

Comment: `my_list = [map(float, line.split(',')) for line in open("Alpha.txt")]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `[[float(i) for i in j] for j in lst]` instead of `[float(i) for i in j]`, the list is nested - you have a list of list of floats, not just a list of floats like you would need for your code to work. Also, it would be better to open the file with a [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) statement, and you might want to use a `try`... `except`... to catch exceptions in case some of the numbers in the file can't be turned into floats - eg. if one line is `1, 2, 34, 56thiswillcrashyourprogramatthemoment, 7, 8, 9`.

Comment: AHHH! thanks so much, i shouldve know it would be nested. Thanks again

Comment: @user2840144 if this answer helped you it would be good to accept it.

Comment: Better would be to do it all in one step `my_list = [map(float, line.split(',')) for line in open("Alpha.txt")]` or `my_list = [[float(i) for i in line.split(',')] for line in open("Alpha.txt")]`

Comment: i like the combination a lot steven, Cheers!

Comment: @StevenRumbalski This is better *iff* the OP is on CPython.  If they are using another python implementation then there is no guarantee that the file will be closed after the comprehension, and in that case `with` is a better method.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7396043/1399279

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `i` is gonna be `['1.2', ' 4.3', ' 7', '0']` and obviously, you can't float a list!

Well, you'll have to use a double iteration:

```
[[float i for i in j] for j in my_list]
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: If the OP wants to maintain the same data structure (i.e. a list of lists) then this will not work because this returns all the numbers as one long list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *map* to cast those strings in floats

```
my_list = map(lambda item: ( map ( lambda s: float(s), item ) ), my_list)
```

You will get some fancy numbers due to python precision

```
>>> map(lambda item: (map(lambda s: float(s), item)), l)
```

[[1.2, 4.2999999999999998, 7.0, 0.0], [3.0, 5.0, 8.1999999999999993, 9.0], [4.0, 3.0, 8.0, 5.5999999999999996], [8.0, 4.0, 3.0, 7.4000000000000004]]

Comment: It isn't Python's precision, it is the underlying architecture of the computer.

Comment: I'm not sure this is easier to read than `[[float(i) for i in j] for j in my_list]`.  Also, in python 3.x, `map` returns a map object, not a list, so to turn this into a list you would need to wrap the whole thing in `list`.

Comment: Also, `map` looks ugly and unpythonic there, better to use a list comprehension IMHO.

Comment: Yep, the optimization/human-readable ratio is not favorable for map

Comment: You could do `map(float, item)` rather than `map(lambda s: float(s), item)`, which seems much better to me.

Comment: Also, with regards to optimization, I don't think `map` is much faster than a list comprehension, indeed when I did a quick test to check I found it was almost twice as slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on doing calculations with your data, you might consider [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and import using [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.genfromtxt('Alpha.txt',delimiter=',')
```

If required, this could be converted to a list like so:

```
my_list = my_array.tolist()
```

Comment: Too complicated. And if he doesn't have numpy?

Comment: It is not complicated. Numpy is available in a [number of distributions](http://www.scipy.org/install.html). Depending on the user's application, it might be preferable to using lists (and therefore is a useful option).