# Python: If I specify stdout with open file function does it close automatically?

Tags: python, stdout

Example:

```
subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=open('status_grid','a'), cwd = folder)
```

is the file status_grid closed automatically?

Comment: You could have tried it...

Comment: @void I could have tried what?

Comment: @IsopycnalOscillation You could have written the simple code in my answer to check.

Comment: @korylprince Yes, now I could have, because now I know how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Which part did you not know how to write? How to check whether a file is closed? How to keep a file object around in a variable and pass it to a function? Or… ?

Comment: @abarnert I did not know how to check whether a file is closed.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/python-is-explicitly-closing-files-important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't:

```
import subprocess
f = open('b','a')
subprocess.call('ls', stdout=f)
print f.closed
```

Output:

```
False
```

Now a better answer might come from unutbu. You don't give your open file a reference, so once your subprocess completes, it's up to the garbage collector how much longer the file is open.

Comment: A better test would be to check [`f.closed`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.closed). There are other reasons `f.write` might fail, but `f.closed` is guaranteed to be true if and only if it's closed…

Answer (score 3):

One way to be sure is

```
with open('status_grid', 'a') as my_file:
    subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=my_file, cwd = folder)
```

Answer (score 2):

If not done explicitly, the file will be closed when it is garbage collected. When the file is garbage collected is not specified by the Python language *per se*.

In CPython, the file is garbage collected when there are no more references to the file object.

With other implementations of Python, such as Jython, garbage collection may happen [completely differently](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/differences.html):

> Jython has "true" garbage collection whereas CPython uses reference
>   counting. This means that in Jython users don't need to worry about
>   handling circular references as these are guaranteed to be collected
>   properly.  On the other hand, users of Jython have no guarantees of
>   when an object will be finalized -- this can cause problems for people
>   who use open("foo", 'r').read() excessively. Both behaviors are
>   acceptable -- and highly unlikely to change.

---

As EMS and Charles Salvia point out, to be sure when the file is closed, it is best to not leave it up to the garbage collector. The best way to do that is to use a [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm), which guarantees the file will be closed when Python leaves the `with-suite`:

```
with open('status_grid','a') as f:
    subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=f, cwd = folder)
```

Answer (score 1):

No it's not.  You can wrap your call in a  `with` statement to ensure the file closes automatically:

```
with open('status_grid','a') as myfile:
   subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=myfile, cwd = folder)
```

Note: with current CPython implementations based on reference counting, the file will be closed when the reference count reaches 0, which will happen immediately in the code you posted.  However, this is just an implementation detail of CPython.  Other implementations may leave the file open indefinitely.  Use the `with` statement to ensure you've written portable code.