# Reading files of same typolgy in a folder

Tags: python, file, function, directory

I need a little help to finish my program. 
I have in a folder 20 files of the same typology, strings with corresponding values.
Is there a way to create a function that opens all the files in this way
`file1 = [line.strip() for line in open("/Python34/elez/file1.txt", "r")]`?

I hope I explained it well.
Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to open 20 files together?

Comment: I need to read every files and write in a new file a summary of them

Answer (score 1):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, isfile

def contents(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        return f.read()

directory = '/Python34/elez'

all_file_contents = [contents(join(directory, filename))
                     for filename in listdir(directory)
                     if isfile(join(directory, filename)]
```

Comment: I think itertools.chain or a generator would be better

Comment: I always get this error
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Python34/elez'`

Comment: @Gulliver You probably have a directory as well as a file. `open(directory)` for example will give you that error. You need to filter them out using `glob` or `os.path.isfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Gulliver this is how i will do it:

```
import os 

all_files = [] ## create a list to keep all the lines for all files 


for file in os.listdir('./'):  ## use list dir to list all files in the dir 
    with open(file, 'r') as f: ## use with to open file 
        fields = [line.strip() for line in f] ## list comprehension to finish reading the field 
        all_fields.extend(fields) ## store in big list
```

For more information about using the with statement to open and read files, please refer to this answer [Correct way to write to files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370968/correct-way-to-write-to-files/27371078?noredirect=1#comment43426406_27371078)