# Upload Image using POST form data in Python-requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests, wechat

I'm working with wechat APIs ...
here I've to upload an image to wechat's server using this API
http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Transferring_Multimedia_Files

```py
url = 'http://file.api.wechat.com/cgi-bin/media/upload?access_token=%s&type=image'%access_token
files = {
    'file': (filename, open(filepath, 'rb')),
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
    'Content-Length': l
}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

I'm not able to post data

Answer (score 76, accepted):

From wechat api doc:

```
curl -F media=@test.jpg "http://file.api.wechat.com/cgi-bin/media/upload?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&type=TYPE"
```

Translate the command above to python:

```
import requests
url = 'http://file.api.wechat.com/cgi-bin/media/upload?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&type=TYPE'
files = {'media': open('test.jpg', 'rb')}
requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Doc: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: I have issue with the comsume of an api-rest, when I try send a request, the response is "message": "No image provided in form-data request", my request is the next: curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --head
er "Accept: application/json" --header "api_key: zzzz" --header "Content-Type: image/jpg" --header "Content-Disposition: form-data" -F media=2016-09-14-154558.jpg "xxxx"

Comment: If someone needs to provide data as a `file object`, for example if you get some image like `some_image = requests.get(url_to_some_image)` and want to post this image to some place, you need to make an image as `file object`. In order to do that, based on the Kev's answer, you need to make `files = {'media': io.BytesIO(some_image.content)}`

Comment: hmm this isnt working for me. The request gives back a 200 code, but a response message of "None", and it is not reaching its destination.

I am printing the buffer read and can confirm its grabbing the file the way you wrote by printing out the buffer strings.

Answer (score 35):

In case if you were to pass the image as part of JSON along with other attributes, you can use the below snippet.
client.py

```
import base64
import json                    

import requests

api = 'http://localhost:8080/test'
image_file = 'sample_image.png'

with open(image_file, "rb") as f:
    im_bytes = f.read()        
im_b64 = base64.b64encode(im_bytes).decode("utf8")

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
  
payload = json.dumps({"image": im_b64, "other_key": "value"})
response = requests.post(api, data=payload, headers=headers)
try:
    data = response.json()     
    print(data)                
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
    print(response.text)
```

server.py

```
import io
import json                    
import base64                  
import logging             
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, abort

app = Flask(__name__)          
app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  
  
@app.route("/test", methods=['POST'])
def test_method():         
    # print(request.json)      
    if not request.json or 'image' not in request.json: 
        abort(400)
             
    # get the base64 encoded string
    im_b64 = request.json['image']

    # convert it into bytes  
    img_bytes = base64.b64decode(im_b64.encode('utf-8'))

    # convert bytes data to PIL Image object
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_bytes))

    # PIL image object to numpy array
    img_arr = np.asarray(img)      
    print('img shape', img_arr.shape)

    # process your img_arr here    
    
    # access other keys of json
    # print(request.json['other_key'])

    result_dict = {'output': 'output_key'}
    return result_dict
  
  
def run_server_api():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
  
  
if __name__ == "__main__":     
    run_server_api()
```

Answer (score 16):

Use this snippet

```
import os
import requests
url = 'http://host:port/endpoint'
with open(path_img, 'rb') as img:
  name_img= os.path.basename(path_img)
  files= {'image': (name_img,img,'multipart/form-data',{'Expires': '0'}) }
  with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post(url,files=files)
    print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: U sir r a genius

Comment: What role does Expires play?

Answer (score 11):

I confronted similar issue when I wanted to post image file to a rest API from Python (Not wechat API though). The solution for me was to use 'data' parameter to post the file in binary data instead of 'files'.  [Requests API reference](http://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/)

```
data = open('your_image.png','rb').read()
r = requests.post(your_url,data=data)
```

Hope this works for your case.

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked for me.
using requests.post to send data. 

 picture_doc = f'{file_path}/{file_name}'
    file = {file: open(picture_doc, 'rb').read()}
requests.post (url, path=path, data = data, files=file)

Answer (score 8):

```
import requests

image_file_descriptor = open('test.jpg', 'rb')
# Requests makes it simple to upload Multipart-encoded files 
files = {'media': image_file_descriptor}
url = '...'
requests.post(url, files=files)
image_file_descriptor.close()
```

Don't forget to close the descriptor, it prevents bugs: [Is explicitly closing files important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/is-explicitly-closing-files-important)

Comment: Where does your `files` come from?

Comment: Use `with open('test.jpg', 'rb') as image file_descriptor:`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have **CURL** then you can **directly get request from Postman**.

```
import requests

url = "your URL"

payload={}
files=[
  ('upload_file',('20220212235319_1509.jpg',open('/20220212235319_1509.jpg','rb'),'image/jpeg'))
]
headers = {
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer yourToken'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
import requests

url = "https://example.com"
payload={}
files=[
  ('file',('myfile.jpg',open('/path/to/myfile.jpg','rb'),'image/jpeg'))
]

response = requests.request("POST", url, auth=("my_username","my_password"), data=payload, files=files)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Rest API to upload images from host to host:

```
import urllib2
import requests

api_host = 'https://host.url.com/upload/'
headers = {'Content-Type' : 'image/jpeg'}
image_url = 'http://image.url.com/sample.jpeg'

img_file = urllib2.urlopen(image_url)

response = requests.post(api_host, data=img_file.read(), headers=headers, verify=False)
```

You can use option verify set to False to omit SSL verification for HTTPS requests.