# Rest Api using python with image as parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to build a REST API in which a user can send an image and another variable as parameters and in return the image function returns the image as response.

Right now I have built a file upload and I processes the uploaded file and it is saved to a location that is given as download link. But I want to make it accessible for other programmers so they can also use the feature and include it in their programs

```
http://Imageprocessr.com/ProcessImage/img="imagefile**"&&para="val"
```

So how to send an image as a parameter and return the image using response just like how we can return other data like texts etc.

Comment: @Zain Khan any idea about this ?

Comment: Is your question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104107/upload-image-using-post-form-data-in-python-requests ?