# Sending image over POST request with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests, postman

I am currently attempting to use Python (3.5) with the Requests library to send a POST request. This POST will send an image file. Here is the sample code:

```
import requests

url = "https://api/address"

files = {'files': open('image.jpg', 'rb')}
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data",
    'accept': "application/json",
    'apikey': "API0KEY0"
    }
response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

However when I run the code I receive a 400 error. I managed to reach the API endpoint, but on the response it states that I failed to send any files.

```
{
  "_id": "0000-0000-0000-0000", 
  "error": "Invalid request", 
  "error_description": "Service requires an image file.", 
  "processed_time": "Tue, 07 Nov 2017 15:28:45 GMT", 
  "request": {
    "files": null, 
    "options": {}, 
"tenantName": "name", 
"texts": []
  }, 
  "status": "FAILED", 
  "status_code": 400, 
  "tenantName": "name"
}
```

The "files" field appears null, which seems a bit odd to me. The POST request worked on Postman, where I used the same header parameters and added image to the body with the "form-data" option (See [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xBE9.png)).

Is there something I am missing here? Is there a better way to send an image file over POST with python?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104107/upload-image-using-post-form-data-in-python-requests) as pointed by another user. However, if you look into it, my current code is similar to what was suggested as the solution and it still didn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload Image using POST form data in Python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104107/upload-image-using-post-form-data-in-python-requests)

Comment: Hello joppich. If you look into it, my current code is similar to what was suggested as the solution and it still didn't work for me.

Comment: You are providing the wrong Content-type.

Answer (score 10):

Use this snippet

```
import os
url = 'http://host:port/endpoint'
with open(path_img, 'rb') as img:
  name_img= os.path.basename(path_img)
  files= {'image': (name_img,img,'multipart/form-data',{'Expires': '0'}) }
  with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post(url,files=files)
    print(r.status_code)
```