# reading image bytes in fastAPI

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi

I have a Python fastAPI server with the following post request function. This function should read an image in the form of bytes and use facebook's nougat OCR model to convert the image into text.

```
@app.post("/predict-from-image/")
async def predict_from_image(img_bytes: bytes) -> str:
    """
    Perform predictions on an image consisting of math text and return the extracted text in Markdown format.

    Args:
        img: A PIL image

    Returns:
        str: The extracted text in Markdown format.
    """

    global model

    # convert the type of img to BytesIO object
    img_bytes = BytesIO(img_bytes)
    images = [img_bytes]

    dataset = ImageDataset(
        images,
        partial(model.encoder.prepare_input, random_padding=False),
    )

    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset,
        batch_size=BATCHSIZE,
        pin_memory=True,
        shuffle=False,
    )

    result = []

    for idx, sample in tqdm(enumerate(dataloader), total=len(dataloader)):
        if sample is None:
            continue
        model_output = model.inference(image_tensors=sample)
        result.append(model_output)

    return json.dumps(result)
```

In another python file, I have this function that calls this post endpoint:

```
def handle_selected_region(self, event):
        if self.selection: # if the selected region exists
            selection_coords = self.canvas.coords(self.selection)
            bbox = self.get_corrected_coordinates(selection_coords)
            cropped_image = self.full_screen_image.crop(bbox)

            # save the cropped image
            cropped_image.save(os.path.join("images", "captured_screen.png"))

            # call nougat OCR API
            cropped_image_bytes = cropped_image.tobytes()
       
            response = requests.post(url="http://127.0.0.1:8503/predict-from-image",
                                     data={"img_bytes": cropped_image_bytes},
                                     headers={"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"})
            
           
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print(response.text)
            else:
                raise Exception(f"Error {response.status_code}: {response.text}")
```

However, the error is raised:

```
C:\Users\a0306\Mathweb\nougat_ocr>python screen_capture.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a0306\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\a0306\Mathweb\nougat_ocr\screen_capture.py", line 164, in y_handler
    self.handle_selected_region(event)
  File "C:\Users\a0306\Mathweb\nougat_ocr\screen_capture.py", line 134, in handle_selected_region
    raise Exception(f"Error {response.status_code}: {response.text}")
Exception: Error 422: {"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["query","img_bytes"],"msg":"Field required","input":null,"url":"https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.1/v/missing"}]}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I am new to fastAPI, so maybe I have written something wrong with both of the functions. Because I also see that I am missing `"query"`, I have also tried to replace

```
response = requests.post(url="http://127.0.0.1:8503/predict-from-image",
                                     data={"img_bytes": cropped_image_bytes},
                                     headers={"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"})
```

with

```
response = requests.post(url="http://127.0.0.1:8503/predict-from-image",
                                     query = "img_bytes",
                                     data = cropped_image_bytes,
                                     headers={"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"})
```

But I then get the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a0306\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\a0306\Mathweb\nougat_ocr\screen_capture.py", line 162, in y_handler
    self.handle_selected_region(event)
  File "C:\Users\a0306\Mathweb\nougat_ocr\screen_capture.py", line 125, in handle_selected_region
    response = requests.post(url="http://127.0.0.1:8503/predict-from-image",
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\a0306\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\a0306\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Session.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71176578/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70711176/17865804)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're posting some data in the form of `application/json` instead of posting it as an image.

What you need to do is to `post` a file as explained below

```
with open(path_img, 'rb') as img:
  name_img= os.path.basename(path_img)
  files= {'img_bytes': (name_img, img, 'multipart/form-data', {'Expires': '0'}) }
  with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post(url,files=files)
```

[Sending image over POST request with Python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162039/sending-image-over-post-request-with-python-requests)

An alternative solution, which is way more complicated, would be to convert the `bytes` as if they were a `string`, send them and reconvert from `string` into `bytes` on the backend. It is more work than what's worth though...