# How do I use requests.put() to upload a file using Python?

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests, fedora-commons

I am trying to use the requests library in Python to upload a file into Fedora commons repository on localhost. I'm fairly certain my main problem is not understanding `open()` / `read()` and what I need to do to send data with an http request.

```
def postBinary(fileName,dirPath,url):
    path = dirPath+'/'+fileName
    print('to ' + url + '\n' + path)
    openBin = {'file':(fileName,open(path,'rb').read())}
    headers = {'Slug': fileName} #not important
    r = requests.put(url, files=openBin,headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'pass'))
    print(r.text)
    print("and the url used:")
    print(r.url)
```

This will successfully upload *a* file in the repository, but it will be slightly larger and corrupted after.  For example an image that was 6.6kb became 6.75kb and was not openable anymore.

**So how should I properly open and upload a file using put in python?**

###Extra details:###

- When I replace `files=openBin` with `data=openBin` I end up with my dictionary and I presume the data as a string. I don't know if that information is helpful or not.
  "file=FILE_NAME.extension&file=TYPE89a%24%02Q%03%E7%FF%00E%5B%19%FC%....
  and the size of the file increases to a number of megabytes
- I am using specifically put because the Fedora RESTful HTTP API end point says to use `put`.

The following command does work:

`curl -u username:password -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -X PUT -T /path/to/someFile.jpeg http://localhost:8080/fcrepo/rest/someFile.jpeg`

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104107/upload-image-using-post-form-data-in-python-requests) (using `POST` method) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload) (using `PUT` method).

Comment: The post information didn't help me, exception sayin wrong protocol for socket. the PUT method link you send I have already tried also no luck:( created a file that is corrupted

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Updated**

Using `requests.put()` with the `files` parameter sends a multipart/form-data encoded request which the server does not seem to be able to handle without corrupting the data, even when the correct content type is declared.

The `curl` command simply performs a PUT with the raw data contained in the body of the request. You can create a similar request by passing the file data in the `data` parameter. Specify the content type in the header:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'image/jpeg', 'Slug': fileName}
r = requests.put(url, data=open(path, 'rb'), headers=headers, auth=('username', 'pass'))
```

You can vary the `Content-type` header to suit the payload as required.

---

Try setting the `Content-type` for the file.

If you are sure that it is a text file then try `text/plain` which you used in your `curl` command - even though you would appear to be uploading a jpeg file? However, for a jpeg image, you should use `image/jpeg`.

Otherwise for arbitrary binary data you can use `application/octet-stream`:

```
openBin = {'file': (fileName, open(path,'rb'), 'image/jpeg' )}
```

Also it is not necessary to explicitly read the file contents in your code, `requests` will do that for you, so just pass the open file handle as shown above.

Comment: hey, I did try content type text plain as the header, and various others. this can be called for any kind of file so I didn't specify.  text plain still works in the curl when downloaded, however does not in python with requests neither does 'image/jpeg' or 'application/octet-stream'. tho I noticed that it has a property in the repository **hasMimeType** which is:
multipart/form-data;boundary=9f74e4d3067e4ce482bdc9e311b58d2d does that help at all?

Comment: also thank you for the tip about read, I had added that before while debugging. ill take it out

Comment: @awscott: it seems that the server does not properly handle multipart/form formatted requests. I have updated my answer to show a simpler method that produces a similar request to that of the working `curl` command.

Comment: you are correct, that worked! thank you! I made the Content-Type header to application/octet-stream as you suggested as well and now it works properly.

Comment: r = requests.put(url, data=open(path, 'rb'), headers=headers, auth=('username', 'pass')) -  Regarding this if the file is too large,  streaming it  without reading them into memory would make more sense ? If yes, how to do that ?

Comment: @Simplecode: [streaming uploads](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads)  is the default behaviour when a file-like object, in this case an open file, is passed in the `data` argument.