# How to resolve error from requests.post() call Segmentation Fault (core dumped)?

Tags: python, nginx, python-requests

I'm sending image to my server for further processing. I'm using Python's `requests` library:

```
path='/home/mark/Pictures/mike.jpeg'

pdb.set_trace()
image = {'image': open(path, 'rb')}
response = requests.post('http://localhost/image/upload', files=image)
if response:
    print(response)
```

when I step through it with debugger it shows me:

```
/home/mark/front_end_android/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py(119)post()
-> return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The image is a standard jpeg file. What am I doing wrong here ?

**Update:**

I found this report from nginx:

```
nginx_1     | 2020/10/21 10:22:29 [warn] 19#19: *3 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000002, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "POST /image/upload HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

^ Does this mean that the image is being held by Nginx proxy ?

Logs from the server:

```
nginx_1     | 2020/10/21 10:22:29 [warn] 19#19: *3 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000002, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "POST /image/upload HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
users_1     | 172.18.0.4 - - [21/Oct/2020 10:22:29] "POST /image/upload HTTP/1.0" 500 -
nginx_1     | 172.18.0.1 - - [21/Oct/2020:10:22:29 +0000] "POST /image/upload HTTP/1.1" 500 39060 "-" "python-requests/2.24.0" "-"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload Image using POST form data in Python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104107/upload-image-using-post-form-data-in-python-requests)

Comment: @AbhinavMathur No, because OP's was using wrong URL format to fetch image from.

Comment: What do you see on the server side ? (localhost)

Comment: @balderman  server just gives me status code 500 (internal server error). Nothing else. No other clue as to what's wrong.

Comment: Do you gave control on the server code? do you understand why it return 500?

Comment: In most cases reason why I get error 500 is because I've got a typo in query for database. But in this case the image doesn't even make it to the server.