# Python Requests - Unable to send image in payload

Tags: python, python-requests

I have created an API test using the Python library Requests. I have a problem when i try to create a new product. The product payload contains an image. See the Postman POST request:-

[image]

I am trying to send an image as part of a JSON payload. See my code below:-

```
import requests
import json
import base64
from Utilities.resources import *
from Utilities.payloads import *
from Utilities.configurations import *

config = getConfig()

login_user_url = config['API']['productionUrl'] + ApiResources.userLogin
create_product_url = 'https://eshop-backend-101.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products'

print(create_product_url)

### Create a new product ###

## First get a user token - Login and get token
login_response = requests.post(login_user_url, json=userPayload(), headers=headerPayload())
get_login_json_response = login_response.json()
token = get_login_json_response['token']

## Use token to create product
print("CREATE A PRODUCT")

## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104107/upload-image-using-post-form-data-in-python-requests
image_file = "D:\\My Training Courses\\Python APUI Testing - Requests\\images\\testImage.jpg"

with open(image_file, "rb") as f:
    im_bytes = f.read()
im_b64 = base64.b64encode(im_bytes).decode("utf8")

headerWithBearerTokenWithFormDataPayload = {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }

bodyPayload = {
                "name": "Product API Test",
                "description": "Product API Test description",
                "richDescription": "Product API Test rich description",
                "image": im_b64,
                "brand": "Product API Test brand",
                "price": 300,
                "category": "5f15d54cf3a046427a1c26e3",
                "countInStock": 10,
                "rating": 4,
                "numReviews": 22,
                "isFeatured": True
        }

## create_product_response = requests.post(create_product_url, json=newProductPayload(im_b64), headers=headerWithBearerTokenPayload(token))
create_product_response = requests.post(create_product_url, json=bodyPayload, headers=headerWithBearerTokenWithFormDataPayload)
print(create_product_response)
```

I am getting the following error:-

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\My Training
> Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in
> urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(   File "D:\My Training Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 398, in
> _make_request
> conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)   File "D:\My Training Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 239, in
> request
> super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)   File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1253,
> in request
> self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
> self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
> self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1047, in _send_output
> self.send(chunk)   File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 969, in send
> self.sock.sendall(data)   File "C:\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1204, in sendall
> v = self.send(byte_view[count:])   File "C:\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1173, in send
> return self._sslobj.write(data) ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\My Training
> Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
> resp = conn.urlopen(   File "D:\My Training Courses\Python APUI Testing - Requests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line
> 785, in urlopen
> retries = retries.increment(   File "D:\My Training Courses\Python APUI Testing - Requests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line
> 550, in increment
> raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)   File "D:\My Training Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 769, in
> reraise
> raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "D:\My Training Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in
> urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(   File "D:\My Training Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 398, in
> _make_request
> conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)   File "D:\My Training Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 239, in
> request
> super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)   File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1253,
> in request
> self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
> self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
> self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1047, in _send_output
> self.send(chunk)   File "C:\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 969, in send
> self.sock.sendall(data)   File "C:\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1204, in sendall
> v = self.send(byte_view[count:])   File "C:\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1173, in send
> return self._sslobj.write(data) urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing
> connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054,
> None))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\My Training
> Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\Automation101EShopAPITests\TEST.py", line 55, in 
> create_product_response = requests.post(create_product_url, json=bodyPayload, headers=headerWithBearerTokenWithFormDataPayload)
> File "D:\My Training Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 117, in post
> return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)   File "D:\My Training Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "D:\My Training Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "D:\My Training Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 645, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "D:\My Training Courses\Python APUI Testing -
> Requests\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 501, in send
> raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',
> ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly
> closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

Comment: Your payload should contain the data of the image file, or in whatever format that API is expecting it [could be base64 string]. But your exception is related to failed to make secure connection to the api url. First you should try to call any simple API and establish that you are able to make API calls to that url.

Comment: did you try some kind of encoding? like base64 as mentioned above

Comment: I tried using 64 encoding. I have added my code to the bottom of the description above.

Comment: I have rewritten the description section of the problem I am having

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) you need to pass a dictionary as a `json` parameter, not a string. Same with `headers` parameter. So remove `json.dumps` from

```py
bodyPayload = json.dumps(
        {
                "name": "Product API Test",
                "description": "Product API Test description",
                "richDescription": "Product API Test rich description",
                "image": im_b64,
                "brand": "Product API Test brand",
                "price": 300,
                "category": "5f15d54cf3a046427a1c26e3",
                "countInStock": 10,
                "rating": 4,
                "numReviews": 22,
                "isFeatured": True
        }
)
```

Comment: I removed the 'json.dumps(' sections. But I am now getting a new error. See above updated issue section.