# Why can't I see the sending request but the photo can still be uploaded?

Tags: python, request

I have a small python project to automatically create images based on sample images. But when it comes to sending images, I encounter a problem, that is, I cannot find a way to upload images.

This is my Chrome request image:
[image: Dev tool]

Tried getting the image code to find the request. But it's not very effective.
Can anyone explain to me how to upload images using python?
Thank you!

I used google translate so the grammar might be a bit strange so please forgive me.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. But [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104107/upload-image-using-post-form-data-in-python-requests) answers how to upload images using Python `requests.post()`.