# Do we need to close a file using open in python?

Tags: python, matlab, file, numpy

Based on what I read on the web, the following seems to be an example of reading data from a binary file consisting of integer data in python:

```
in_file = open('12345.bin', 'rb');
x = np.fromfile(in_file, dtype = 'int32');
```

In Matlab, I think the corresponding command is:

```
in_file = fopen('12345.bin', 'rb');
x = fread(in_file, 'int32');
fclose(in_file);
```

In Matlab, a file is supposed to be closed using `fclose` after finishing using it. Is there anything corresponding to this in NumPy?

Comment: The analog in python is `in_file.close()`. However, if you forget to do that, python will automatically close the file when the function returns

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/is-explicitly-closing-files-important

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: CPython will, but it's not a language guarantee in general (PyPy, Jython, and IronPython might get around to closing the file at some point, but not at a predictable time).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The python equivalent is `in_file.close()`. While it's always good practice to close any files you open, python is a little more forgiving - it will automatically close any open file handlers when your function returns (or when your script finishes, if you open a file outside a function).

On the other hand, if you like using python's nested indentation scopes, then you might consider doing this (valid as of python 2.7):

```
with open('1234.bin', 'rb') as infile:
    x = np.fromfile(infile, dtype='int32')
# other stuff to do outside of the file opening scope
```

**EDIT**: [As @ShadowRanger pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503576/dont-we-need-to-close-a-file-using-open-in-python?noredirect=1#comment56749337_34503576) CPython will automatically close your file handlers at function-return/end-of-script. Other versions of python will also do this, though not in a predictable way/time

Answer (score 3):

You need to close an opened file:

```
f=open('file')
f.close()
```