# Python: Assigning user input as key in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, split, tuples

**Problem**
I was trying to assign user input as a key in a dictionary. If user input is a key then print out its value, else print invalid key. The problem is the keys and the values will be from a text file. For simplicity I will just use random data for the text. Any help would be appreciated.

**file.txt**

Dog,bark
Cat,meow
bird,chirp

**Code**

```
def main():
    file = open("file.txt")
    for i in file:
        i = i.strip()
        animal, sound = i.split(",")
        dict = {animal : sound}

    keyinput = input("Enter animal to know what it sounds like: ")
    if keyinput in dict:
        print("The ",keyinput,sound,"s")
    else:
        print("The animal is not in the list")
```

Comment: What's your question? You should read [mcve].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On every iteration of the loop, you are *redefining the dictionary*, instead, add new entries:

```
d = {}
for i in file:
    i = i.strip()
    animal, sound = i.split(",")
    d[animal] = sound
```

Then, you can access the dictionary items by key:

```
keyinput = input("Enter animal to know what it sounds like: ")
if keyinput in d:
    print("The {key} {value}s".format(key=keyinput, value=d[keyinput]))
else:
    print("The animal is not in the list")
```

Note that I've also changed the dictionary variable name from `dict` to `d`, since `dict` is a poor variable name choice because it is *shadowing the built-in `dict`*.

Also, I've improved the way you construct the reporting string and used a [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead. If you would enter `Dog`, the output would be `The Dog barks`.

---

You can also initialize the dictionary in one line using the `dict()` constructor:

```
d = dict(line.strip().split(",") for line in file)
```

As a side note, [to follow the best practices and keep your code portable and reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7396043/771848), use the [`with` context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) when opening the file - it would take care about closing it properly:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

OP, I've written some verbose explanatory notes in the code and fixed a few issues; I might have overlooked something but check it out.

- For one, avoid using `dict` as a variable name since it shadows Python's bult-in `dict` method.
- Remember that , in most cases, you need to declare variables before a loop to make them accessible *after* the loop; this applies to your dictionary.
- Also, remember to close files after reading/writing unless you use `with open(filename) ...`

  ```
  def main():
      # declare a new, empty dictionary to hold your animal species and sounds. 
      # Note that I'm avoiding the use of "dict" as a variable name since it 
      # shadows/overrides the built-in method 
      animal_dict = {}
      file = open("file.txt")
      for i in file:
          i = i.strip()
          animal, sound = i.split(",")
          animal_dict[animal] = sound

      # Remember to close your files after reading
      file.close()

      keyinput = input("Enter animal to know what it sounds like: ")
      if keyinput in animal_dict:

          # here, keyinput is the string/key and to do a lookup
          # in the dictionary, you use brackets. 
          # animal_dict[keyinput] thus returns the sound

          print("The ",keyinput,animal_dict[keyinput],"s")
      else:
          print("The animal is not in the list")
  ```

Comment: Dumping code without an explanation isn't helpful for OP or future readers.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Working on it... :)

Answer (score 1):

There were comments on every line I changed something explaining what I  changed, but to help readability, I'm putting them here too.

- On Line 2 I instantiated a dictionary - you were previously
  re-defining a dictionary for each line
- On Line 7 I changed your
  code to add something to the dictionary instead of just creating a
  new one. That's proper dictionary syntax.
- On Line 10 I changed "if
  keyinput in dict" to "if keyinput in dict.keys()", since you're
  checking to see if the animal exists, and the animals in your file
  become the keys of the dictionary.

  ```
  def main():

    dict = {} #Create an empty dictionary to add to
    file = open("file.txt")
    for i in file:
        i = i.strip()
        animal, sound = i.split(",")
        dict[animal] = sound #This is how you add a key/value pair to a dictionary in Python

    keyinput = input("Enter animal to know what it sounds like: ")
    if keyinput in dict.keys(): #Add .keys() to iterate through dictionary keys
        print("The ",keyinput,sound,"s")
    else:
        print("The animal is not in the list")
  ```

Comment: @MorganThrapp There are comments on every line I changed, did you see those? It wasn't just a code dump.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I dont think Ian was just dumping code, please remove your downvote

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not name a variable the same as a keyword. Secondly, the way you put the input into the dictionary will overwrite the previous values. You need to create the dictionary and then add the new values.
Third, you output the value `sound` without getting it from the dictionary

`dict` as a variable should be named `mydict`

create `mydict = {}` **before the initial loop**

set `mydict[animal] = sound` in the first loop

```
mydict['dog'] = 'bark' # This is what happens
```

print `keyinput` and `mydict[keyinput]` if it is in the list.

You can also use `mysound = mydict.get(keyinput, "not in dictionary")` instead of the if.

[Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)