# Slurp file in python

Tags: python, file, with-statement

To slurp a file I can do either:

```
with open('foo', 'r') as fd:
   content = fd.read()
```

or

```
content = open('foo').read()
```

Is there any advantages to use the `with` statement here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method ensures that the file will be closed no matter what. It's like doing:

```
try:
    fd = open('foo')
    content = fd.read()
    # ... do stuff here
finally:
    fd.close()
```

Comment: Isn't also the case with the latter solution? Once the file is read the gc will automatically close the file pointer right?

Comment: I will leave the explanation to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7396043/5762711) answer, which does it beutifully :)