# python closing file when using in-line "for" statement

Tags: python, file

I am counting the lines in a file using the following:

```
n = sum(1 for line in open(counts_file_location))
```

Questions:

1. does the file `counts_file_location` gets closed automatically at the end of "for" loop?
2. if the file does not get closed automatically, how do I close it? There is no file_pointer assigned to to the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is explicitly closing files important?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/is-explicitly-closing-files-important)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)

Comment: Just don't open files this way. Use a `with` statement. It's much safer, especially on Python implementations that aren't CPython.

Answer (score 1):

It should, but it is implementation dependent

If you want to make sure the file gets closed, try `with open`:

```
with open(counts_file_location) as file:
    n = sum(1 for line in file)
```

Comment: This isn't addressed to the specific question -- you mean `n = sum(1 for line in file)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single line to open the file, close the file, and get the number of lines:

```
lineCount = (lambda a: (sum(1 for line in a), a.close()))(open(counts_file_location))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
with open(counts_file_location) as my_file:
  for line in my_file:
    count += 1
print count
```

It's not a one-liner, but it's readable, works fine and closes the file.

If you need it often, you could define the corresponding function.