# Creating a dictionary from a txt file?

Tags: python

So say I have a .txt file called example.txt, for example:

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
key2 value3
```

I want to create a dictionary from this txt file. In this case I want it to be 
example_dict = {'key1':'value2', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3'}
All the items in the txt file are strings and have a newline before the next item. 
So far the only code I have is opening the file:

```
example_dict = {}
with open('example.txt', 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
```

I don't understand how to go about creating this dictionary from the txt file.

Comment: if your keys and values at same place as you shown in example then you can try this different method with regex :

https://pastebin.com/hp2wprAC

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
new_file = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('example.txt')]
final_dict = {a:b for a, b in new_file}
```

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: LGTM. Don't understand the downvote.

Comment: Python doesn't guarantee that your file will be closed right away if you use `open` in a list comprehension like this (it has to be garbage collected, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/is-explicitly-closing-files-important)). So it is better practice to use a context manager (`with`). Further, you can use the `dict()` builtin instead of the comprehension. The downvote is for answering such a clear duplicate, and the answer's content itself.