# Importing to a list from a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

numbers.txt:

```
5      6
3      8
9      10
```

I want to create a list from a numbers.txt, my list should be [[5,6],[3,8],[9,10]

But I keep getting \t(between numbers) and \n(at the end, ex. 10\n etc.) in the output. How can I fix that? I should be getting [[5,6], [3,8], [9,10]]

My code is:

```
file=open("numbers.txt","r")
l=[]
for line in file:
    l.append(line.split(','))

print(l)
```

thanks(note: tab is used between two numbers in every line)

Comment: Try just `line.split()` (without an argument)?

Comment: Why are you splitting on `,` when there are no commas in your file?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you got tab `\t` separated values. This is my fav:

```
with open('numbers.txt') as f:
    # split the file by rows and rows by separator
    l = [i.split('\t') for i in f.read().split('\n')]

print(l) # [['5', '6'], ['3', '8'], ['9', '10']]
```

[With open...](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) makes sure that the file is closed after.

---

Other alternatives would include importing libraries. Numpy and pandas are the two leading packages to deal with arrays/data/tables/matrixes. Both of them will evaluate your input (and in this case it would be stored as integers). Numpy was suggested by [Joran Beasley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47996874/7386332).

```
import numpy as np
l = np.genfromtxt('numbers.txt').tolist()

import pandas as pd
l = pd.read_csv('numbers.txt', sep='\t', header=None).values.tolist()
```

If you need it to be integers or float, change code below to one of these:

```
l = [list(map(int,i.split('\t'))) for i in f.read().split('\n')]
# [[5, 6], [3, 8], [9, 10]]
l = [list(map(float,i.split('\t'))) for i in f.read().split('\n')]
# [[5.0, 6.0], [3.0, 8.0], [9.0, 10.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
l.append(','.join(line.split()))
```

`split` without arguments will split your line by whitespaces, include tab or newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
dat = numpy.genfromtxt("numbers.txt")
```

Is probably how i would do it ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
print(list(map(lambda x:x.split(),open('file.txt','r'))))
```

output:

```
[['5', '6'], ['3', '8'], ['9', '10']]
```

P.S: you can read this too if you have doubt what happend if you don't [close the file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/is-explicitly-closing-files-important)