# Regular expression strategy for newbies

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a long text file with each line of pseudocode that looks like this:

`big house --> ['living room', 'kitchen', 'bathroom']`

There are about 700 lines like this that need to be transformed to a python dictionary in the format:

```
{'big house' : ['living room', 'kitchen', 'bathroom']}
```

As you can see, for each line, I need to make brackets at the beginning and end, replace the "-->" with ":" and place quotes around the dictionary key. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Would the best strategy be a find and replace for "-->" and then add brackets to beginning and end in a separate regex, then tackle the key in another regex?*

Comment: I am new to regex and was looking for a strategy, one expression or to break it up.

Answer (score 4):

You can get your required output without regex:

**Ex:**

```
import ast
s = """big house --> ['living room', 'kitchen', 'bathroom']
big house2 --> ['living room', 'kitchen', 'bathroom']"""
d = {}
for i in s.split("\n"):
    val = i.split("-->")
    d[val[0].strip()] = ast.literal_eval(val[1].strip())
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'big house2': ['living room', 'kitchen', 'bathroom'], 'big house': ['living room', 'kitchen', 'bathroom']}
```

- Split your text at "-->" and use `index  as key` & `index 1 as value`.
- Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the string list to list object.

**Using Regex:**

```
import re
import ast
s = """big house --> ['living room', 'kitchen', 'bathroom']
big house2 -->  ['living room', 'kitchen', 'bathroom']"""
d = {}
for i in re.findall("(.*)\s+\-->\s+(.*)", s):
    d[i[0].strip()] = ast.literal_eval(i[1].strip())
print(d)
#{'big house2': ['living room', 'kitchen', 'bathroom'], 'big house': ['living room', 'kitchen', 'bathroom']}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I had my head stuck in a text editor thinking that the only solution would be to use regex. I will go ahead and run in Python instead. Much appreciated!

Comment: I thik the dictionary values should be arrays instead of string.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way of achieving what you need:

```
import ast

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    result = {}
    for line in f:
        line = line.split('-->')
        cleanLine = [l.strip() for l in line]
        result[cleanLine[0]] = ast.literal_eval(cleanLine[1])
```

`ast.literal_eval` will turn list string into actual list.

Answer (score 3):

The regex "text editor" solution you asked for that would work in most text editors with a regex find mode would be:

```
Find:    (.*) --> (.*)
Replace: {'$1': $2}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Fixed the problem. I was way overthinking it. Thanks Chris!

Answer (score 1):

You can try dict comprehension :

```
import re
import ast
print({re.search(r"(\w.+)?-->\s(\['\w.+?\])", line).group(1).strip():ast.literal_eval(re.search(r"(\w.+)?-->\s(\['\w.+?\])",line).group(2)) for line in open('new_filea','r')})
```

output:

```
{'big house': ['living room', 'kitchen', 'bathroom']}
```

P.S: you can read this too if you have doubt what happend if you don't [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/is-explicitly-closing-files-important) the file.