# How to change output to a text file?

Tags: python

I made a code which prints random emails. Now I want these emails in a text file. Here's my code:

```
import random
domain = ["@gmail.com", "@hotmail.com", "@outlook.com", "@yahoo.in", "@protonmail.com"]
names = ["John", "Leonardo", "Russel", "Danny", "Mac", "Fredrick", "Mark"]
for i in range(10):
   randname = random.randrange(len(names))
   randmail = random.randrange(len(domain))
   print(names[randname] + domain[randmail])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create a `textFile.txt` and add all your random emails to the file.

```
import random
domain = ["@gmail.com", "@hotmail.com", "@outlook.com", "@yahoo.in", "@protonmail.com"]
names = ["John", "Leonardo", "Russel", "Danny", "Mac", "Fredrick", "Mark"]
TxtFile = open("textFile.txt","w")
for i in range(10):
   randname = random.randrange(len(names))
   randmail = random.randrange(len(domain))
   print(names[randname] + domain[randmail])
   TxtFile.write(names[randname] + domain[randmail]+"\n")
TxtFile.close()
```

Comment: You have opened txt file but didn't closed it :/

Comment: @PySaad closed it now :|

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, is it important to close the file?

Comment: It all depends check this out for more - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/is-explicitly-closing-files-important

Comment: Alright, thank you very much.