# Uses of io.ReadCloser

Tags: go, io

Could someone please explain (or/and share examples) when and why readers should  to be closed explicitly, i.e. implement io.ReadCloser, not just io.Reader.

Comment: Any time you need to close your reader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example, when you are working with files, or any resource that should be closed to release the allocated resource (or memory for example for your resource, e.g. `C` code calling from `Go`).
You may use it when you have `Read` and `Close` methods, an example to show that you may use one common function to work with different types using `io.ReadCloser`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("./main.go")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    doIt(f)
    doIt(os.Stdin)
}
func doIt(rc io.ReadCloser) {
    defer rc.Close()
    buf := make([]byte, 4)
    n, err := rc.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", buf[:n])
}
```

Run and enter `12345` as an input, Output:

```
pack
12345
1234
```

See also:
[Does Go automatically close resources if not explicitly closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58351084/does-go-automatically-close-resources-if-not-explicitly-closed)

Answer (score 4):

It's for an explicit definition of Reader and Closer interface. So let's say you write  some functionality that reads data, but you also want to close resource after doing it (again not to leak descriptors).

```
func ...(r io.ReaderCloser) {
    defer r.Close()
    ... // some reading
}
```

anything you pass in it will need to have both interfaces defined, is it os.File or any custom struct, in this case, you are forcing client of your API to define `Read` and `Close` interfaces implementations, not just io.Reader.