# Is it ok to use open inline with json.dump

Tags: json, python-3.x, file

If I want to write data to a file using json library, Is it ok if I do this?:

```
...
json.dump(my_data, open('my_file_path', 'w+'))
...
```

Or do I have to do this?:

```
...
with open('my_file_path', 'w+') as my_file:
    json.dump(my_data, my_file)
...
```

Does the first option also closes the file immediatly?

Comment: The `with` context manager also *closes* the file when the context ends, so it's probably better.

Comment: I know that, but because I am not creating any reference to the file, maybe I get the same result with the inline option

Comment: As I understand it the file is closed when the handle is garbage collected, but you don't have the same control over when that happens.

Comment: I had a similar question and people pointed me to another question with answers, so I flag this one as duplicate too for others to find good answers. go here -> [Is explicitly closing files important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/is-explicitly-closing-files-important)